# What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile?

Tags: python, dynamic, eval, exec

I've been looking at dynamic evaluation of Python code, and come across the `eval()` and `compile()` functions, and the `exec` statement.

Can someone please explain the difference between `eval` and `exec`, and how the different modes of `compile()` fit in?

Comment: is this the same as asking: what is the difference between `eval` and `$(...)`?

Answer (score 735, accepted):

## The short answer, or TL;DR

Basically, [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) is used to **eval**uate a single dynamically generated Python expression, and [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) is used to **exec**ute dynamically generated Python code only for its side effects.

`eval` and `exec` have these two differences:

1. `eval` accepts only a **single expression**, `exec` can take a code block that has Python statements: loops, `try: except:`, `class` and function/method `def`initions and so on.

   An expression in Python is whatever you can have as the value in a variable assignment:

   ```
   a_variable = (anything you can put within these parentheses is an expression)
   ```
2. `eval` **returns the value** of the given expression, whereas `exec` ignores the return value from its code, and always returns `None` (in Python 2 it is a statement and cannot be used as an expression, so it really does not return anything).

In versions 1.0 - 2.7, `exec` was a statement, because CPython needed to produce a different kind of code object for functions that used `exec` for its side effects inside the function.

In Python 3, `exec` is a function; its use has no effect on the compiled bytecode of the function where it is used.

---

Thus basically:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> eval('37 + a')   # it is an expression
42
>>> exec('37 + a')   # it is an expression statement; value is ignored (None is returned)
>>> exec('a = 47')   # modify a global variable as a side effect
>>> a
47
>>> eval('a = 47')  # you cannot evaluate a statement
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    a = 47
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

The `compile` in `'exec'` mode compiles any number of statements into a bytecode that implicitly always returns `None`, whereas in `'eval'` mode it compiles a *single* expression into bytecode that *returns* the value of that expression.

```
>>> eval(compile('42', '<string>', 'exec'))  # code returns None
>>> eval(compile('42', '<string>', 'eval'))  # code returns 42
42
>>> exec(compile('42', '<string>', 'eval'))  # code returns 42,
>>>                                          # but ignored by exec
```

In the `'eval'` mode (and thus with the `eval` function if a string is passed in), the `compile` raises an exception if the source code contains statements or anything else beyond a single expression:

```
>>> compile('for i in range(3): print(i)', '<string>', 'eval')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    for i in range(3): print(i)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Actually the statement *"eval accepts only a single expression"* applies only when a string (which contains Python *source code*) is passed to `eval`. Then it is internally compiled to bytecode using [`compile(source, '<string>', 'eval')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) This is where the difference really comes from.

If a `code` object (which contains Python *bytecode*) is passed to `exec` or `eval`, *they behave identically*, excepting for the fact that `exec` ignores the return value, still returning `None` always. So it is possible use `eval` to execute something that has statements, if you just `compile`d it into bytecode before instead of passing it as a string:

```
>>> eval(compile('if 1: print("Hello")', '<string>', 'exec'))
Hello
>>>
```

works without problems, even though the compiled code contains statements. It still returns `None`, because that is the return value of the code object returned from `compile`.

In the `'eval'` mode (and thus with the `eval` function if a string is passed in), the `compile` raises an exception if the source code contains statements or anything else beyond a single expression:

```
>>> compile('for i in range(3): print(i)', '<string>'. 'eval')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    for i in range(3): print(i)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

## The longer answer, a.k.a the gory details

### `exec` and `eval`

The [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function (which was [a statement in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec)) is used for executing a dynamically created statement or program:

```
>>> program = '''
for i in range(3):
    print("Python is cool")
'''
>>> exec(program)
Python is cool
Python is cool
Python is cool
>>>
```

The [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function does the same for a [single expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html), *and* returns the value of the expression:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> my_calculation = '42 * a'
>>> result = eval(my_calculation)
>>> result
84
```

`exec` and `eval` both accept the program/expression to be run either as a `str`, `unicode` or `bytes` object containing source code, or as a *`code` object* which contains Python bytecode.

If a `str`/`unicode`/`bytes` containing source code was passed to `exec`, it behaves equivalently to:

```
exec(compile(source, '<string>', 'exec'))
```

and `eval` similarly behaves equivalent to:

```
eval(compile(source, '<string>', 'eval'))
```

---

Since all expressions can be used as statements in Python (these are called the `Expr` nodes in the Python [abstract grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar); the opposite is not true), you can always use `exec` if you do not need the return value. That is to say, you can use either `eval('my_func(42)')` or `exec('my_func(42)')`, the difference being that `eval` returns the value returned by `my_func`, and `exec` discards it:

```
>>> def my_func(arg):
...     print("Called with %d" % arg)
...     return arg * 2
... 
>>> exec('my_func(42)')
Called with 42
>>> eval('my_func(42)')
Called with 42
84
>>>
```

Of the 2, only `exec` accepts source code that contains statements, like `def`, `for`, `while`, `import`, or `class`, the assignment statement (a.k.a `a = 42`), or entire programs:

```
>>> exec('for i in range(3): print(i)')
0
1
2
>>> eval('for i in range(3): print(i)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    for i in range(3): print(i)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Both `exec` and `eval` accept 2 additional positional arguments - `globals` and `locals` - which are the global and local variable scopes that the code sees. These default to the `globals()` and `locals()` within the scope that called `exec` or `eval`, but any dictionary can be used for `globals` and any `mapping` for `locals` (including `dict` of course). These can be used not only to restrict/modify the variables that the code sees, but are often also used for capturing the variables that the `exec`uted code creates:

```
>>> g = dict()
>>> l = dict()
>>> exec('global a; a, b = 123, 42', g, l)
>>> g['a']
123
>>> l
{'b': 42}
```

(If you display the value of the entire `g`, it would be much longer, because `exec` and `eval` add the built-ins module as `__builtins__` to the globals automatically if it is missing).

In Python 2, the official syntax for the `exec` statement is actually `exec code in globals, locals`, as in

```
>>> exec 'global a; a, b = 123, 42' in g, l
```

However the alternate syntax `exec(code, globals, locals)` has always been accepted too (see below).

### `compile`

The [`compile(source, filename, mode, flags=0, dont_inherit=False, optimize=-1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) built-in can be used to speed up repeated invocations of the same code with `exec` or `eval` by compiling the source into a `code` object beforehand. The `mode` parameter controls the kind of code fragment the `compile` function accepts and the kind of bytecode it produces. The choices are `'eval'`, `'exec'` and `'single'`:

- `'eval'` mode expects a single expression, and will produce bytecode that when run will return the value of **that expression**:

  ```
  >>> dis.dis(compile('a + b', '<string>', 'eval'))
    1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
                3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
                6 BINARY_ADD
                7 RETURN_VALUE
  ```
- `'exec'` accepts any kinds of python constructs from single expressions to whole modules of code, and executes them as if they were module top-level statements. The code object returns `None`:

  ```
  >>> dis.dis(compile('a + b', '<string>', 'exec'))
    1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
                3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
                6 BINARY_ADD
                7 POP_TOP                             <- discard result
                8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)   <- load None on stack
               11 RETURN_VALUE                        <- return top of stack
  ```
- `'single'` is a limited form of `'exec'` which accepts a source code containing a **single** statement (or multiple statements separated by `;`) if the last statement is an expression statement, the resulting bytecode also *prints the `repr` of the value of that expression to the standard output(!)*.

  An `if`-`elif`-`else` chain, a loop with `else`, and `try` with its `except`, `else` and `finally` blocks is considered a single statement.

  A source fragment containing 2 top-level statements is an error for the `'single'`, except in Python 2 there is *a bug* that sometimes allows multiple toplevel statements in the code; only the first is compiled; the rest are ignored:

  In Python 2.7.8:

  ```
  >>> exec(compile('a = 5\na = 6', '<string>', 'single'))
  >>> a
  5
  ```

  And in Python 3.4.2:

  ```
  >>> exec(compile('a = 5\na = 6', '<string>', 'single'))
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 1
      a = 5
          ^
  SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
  ```

  This is very useful for making interactive Python shells. However, the value of the expression is *not returned*, even if you `eval` the resulting code.

Thus greatest distinction of `exec` and `eval` actually comes from the `compile` function and its modes.

---

In addition to compiling source code to bytecode, `compile` supports compiling [*abstract syntax trees*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar) (parse trees of Python code) into `code` objects; and source code into abstract syntax trees (the `ast.parse` is written in Python and just calls `compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)`); these are used for example for modifying source code on the fly, and also for dynamic code creation, as it is often easier to handle the code as a tree of nodes instead of lines of text in complex cases.

---

While `eval` only allows you to evaluate a string that contains a single expression, you can `eval` a whole statement, or even a whole module that has been `compile`d into bytecode; that is, with Python 2, `print` is a statement, and cannot be `eval`led directly:

```
>>> eval('for i in range(3): print("Python is cool")')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    for i in range(3): print("Python is cool")
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`compile` it with `'exec'` mode into a `code` object and you can **`eval`  it**; the `eval` function will return `None`.

```
>>> code = compile('for i in range(3): print("Python is cool")',
                   'foo.py', 'exec')
>>> eval(code)
Python is cool
Python is cool
Python is cool
```

If one looks into [`eval`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ec6ed10d611e/Python/bltinmodule.c#l805) and [`exec`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ec6ed10d611e/Python/bltinmodule.c#l882) source code in CPython 3, this is very evident; they both call `PyEval_EvalCode` with same arguments, the only difference being that [`exec` explicitly returns `None`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ec6ed10d611e/Python/bltinmodule.c#l903).

### Syntax differences of `exec` between Python 2 and Python 3

One of the major differences in Python **2** is that `exec` is a statement and `eval` is a built-in function (both are built-in functions in Python 3).
It is a well-known fact that the official syntax of `exec` in Python 2 is `exec code [in globals[, locals]]`.

Unlike majority of the Python 2-to-3 [porting](http://python3porting.com/differences.html#exec) [guides](http://python-future.org/reference.html?highlight=exec#future.utils.exec_) [seem](http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html#exec-statement) [to suggest](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200910/running_the_same_code_on_python_2x_and_3x.html), the `exec` statement in CPython 2 can be also used with syntax that *looks* **exactly** like the `exec` function invocation in Python 3. The reason is that Python 0.9.9 had the `exec(code, globals, locals)` built-in function! And that built-in function was replaced with `exec` statement [somewhere before Python 1.0 release](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/fccd415e2eb8/Python/ceval.c).

Since it was desirable to not break backwards compatibility with Python 0.9.9, [Guido van Rossum added a compatibility hack in 1993](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/fccd415e2eb8/Python/ceval.c#l2521): if the `code` was a tuple of length 2 or 3, and `globals` and `locals` were not passed into the `exec` statement otherwise, the `code` would be interpreted as if the 2nd and 3rd element of the tuple were the `globals` and `locals` respectively. The compatibility hack was not mentioned even in [Python 1.4 documentation (the earliest available version online)](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/ref/ref6.html#HDR10); and thus was not known to many writers of the porting guides and tools, until it was [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) again [in November 2012](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-November/122651.html):

> The first expression may also be a tuple of length 2 or 3. In this case, the optional parts must be omitted. The form `exec(expr, globals)` is equivalent to `exec expr in globals`, while the form `exec(expr, globals, locals)` is equivalent to `exec expr in globals, locals`. The tuple form of `exec` provides compatibility with Python 3, where `exec` is a function rather than a statement.

Yes, in CPython 2.7 that it is handily referred to as being a forward-compatibility option (why confuse people over that there is a backward compatibility option at all), 
when it actually had been there for *backward-compatibility for two decades*.

Thus while `exec` is a statement in Python 1 and Python 2, and a built-in function in Python 3 and Python 0.9.9,

```
>>> exec("print(a)", globals(), {'a': 42})
42
```

has had identical behaviour in possibly every widely released Python version ever; and works in Jython 2.5.2, PyPy 2.3.1 (Python 2.7.6) and IronPython 2.6.1 too (kudos to them following the undocumented behaviour of CPython closely).

What you cannot do in Pythons 1.0 - 2.7 with its compatibility hack, is to store the return value of `exec` into a variable:

```
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = exec('print(42)')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = exec('print(42)')
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(which wouldn't be useful in Python 3 either, as `exec` always returns `None`), or pass a reference to `exec`:

```
>>> call_later(exec, 'print(42)', delay=1000)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    call_later(exec, 'print(42)', delay=1000)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Which a pattern that someone might actually have used, though unlikely;

Or use it in a list comprehension:

```
>>> [exec(i) for i in ['print(42)', 'print(foo)']
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [exec(i) for i in ['print(42)', 'print(foo)']
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

which is abuse of list comprehensions (use a `for` loop instead!).

Comment: Was `[i for i in globals().values() if hasattr(i, '__call__')][0]` a statement or expression? If it was an expression, why can't I use it with `@` as decorator?

Comment: it is an expression. `42` is also an expression, and you cannot use it with `@` as a decorator.

Comment: The decorator syntax is [`decorator ::=  "@" dotted_name ["(" [parameter_list [","]] ")"] NEWLINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-dotted_name); i.e. you cannot use arbitrary expressions as decorators, ONLY a (maybe dotted) identifier, followed by optional call arguments.

Comment: Not anything that can be put on the right side of an assignment and still compile is an expression. For example, `a = b = c` is a perfectly valid statement, as is its right-hand side `b = c` - which is not an expression.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to also mention `ast.literal_eval`, which is more limited but also much safer to use than `eval` and `exec`.  I use it a lot to evaluate a string which may represent a `bool`, `int`, `float`, ...

Comment: @florisla good point, though this answer is rather long already. Also it is possible to crash Python 2 with literal eval

Comment: if I use exec("my_uuid = uuid.uuid1()") can't I then refer to my_uuid in subsequent lines of my code? Isn't it thread safe?  I am doing this because I want to dynamically execute the code from a text element in a database row that can change as needed.

Comment: @MikeOliver "it depends". It is perhaps better to use a custom locals dictionary!
i.e. `l = {}; exec("my_uuid = uuid.uuid1()", globals(), l)` and afterwards you can use `l['my_uuid']`.

Comment: slightly unrelated, in bash, what is the difference between `eval` and `$(...)`?

Answer (score 216):

1. `exec` is not an expression: a statement in Python 2.x, and a function in Python 3.x. It compiles and immediately evaluates a statement or set of statement contained in a string. Example:

   ```
    exec('print(5)')           # prints 5.
    # exec 'print 5'     if you use Python 2.x, nor the exec neither the print is a function there
    exec('print(5)\nprint(6)')  # prints 5{newline}6.
    exec('if True: print(6)')  # prints 6.
    exec('5')                 # does nothing and returns nothing.
   ```
2. `eval` is a built-in function (**not** a statement), which evaluates an expression and returns the value that expression produces. Example:

   ```
    x = eval('5')              # x <- 5
    x = eval('%d + 6' % x)     # x <- 11
    x = eval('abs(%d)' % -100) # x <- 100
    x = eval('x = 5')          # INVALID; assignment is not an expression.
    x = eval('if 1: x = 4')    # INVALID; if is a statement, not an expression.
   ```
3. `compile` is a lower level version of `exec` and `eval`. It does not execute or evaluate your statements or expressions, but returns a code object that can do it. The modes are as follows:
4. `compile(string, '', 'eval')` returns the code object that would have been executed had you done `eval(string)`. Note that you *cannot* use statements in this mode; only a (single) expression is valid.
5. `compile(string, '', 'exec')` returns the code object that would have been executed had you done `exec(string)`. You can use any number of statements here.
6. `compile(string, '', 'single')` is like the `exec` mode but expects exactly one expression/statement, eg `compile('a=1 if 1 else 3', 'myf', mode='single')`

Comment: In Python 3, `exec()` now is in fact a function.

Comment: Since (as you point out), `exec` is a statement in the version you were targeting, it's deceptive to include those parens, and if you try to use the `in globals, locals`, also buggy.

Comment: This answer is mostly helpful, but emphasizes some confusing things about `exec` and `eval`. Namely: 

 1) Whether the names `exec` and `eval` are statements (e.g. `return`, `yield`) or expressions (actually a subset of statements disjoint to `return`, `yield`, etc) is **irrelevant** to the point of the question. The question is not asking for a clarification on the Python grammar.
 2) The answer uses `print` statements in the `exec` examples. Output is **a side effect** of `print`. Interactively, `exec('print ...')` will "put something on the line", but this is not a (returnable) evaluation.

Comment: @MikeGraham `exec` **supports parentheses and function like invocation in Python 2**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala insofar as assignment 'supports parentheses' because you can do `x = (y)`, that might be true. Another statement-turned-function is `print`; compare the result of `print(1, 2, 3)` in python 2 and 3.

Comment: @habnabit not like that. Please read the bottom of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29456463/918959) here and be surprised.

Comment: @habnabit no, there's a specific [parenthesis-based syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) for the `exec` statement in Python 2.x which provides compatibility with the `exec()` function in Python 3.x.

Comment: The `'single'` mode description is wrong. a) it does not ignore but should be a compile-time error to have more than one statement, b) if the statement is an expression statement, its value is **printed** to `stdout`.

Comment: (though it is true that *sometimes* the `'single'` mode ignores the extra statement and does not raise an error, this should be considered more a bug than a feature since it seems it is fixed at least in Python 3.4)

Answer (score 54):

exec is for statement and does not return anything.
eval is for expression and returns value of expression.

expression means "something" while statement means "do something".

Comment: The second paragraph is such a simplification that it almost becomes a lie, an expression can very much do something if it includes a function call.