# Why am I getting errors with execs nested in functions?

Tags: python, compiler-construction

I'm trying to make a "compiler" for my game (so that people could do intresting stuff but not inject code), for mainly declaritive "code" (It would look like this: `{"player_location":"IceHall.A7", "print", "You are teleported somewhere", "tiles":{"FirePlace.B3":{'Type':"Corner", "Actions+":{....}}}}`. This is how a action is represented; It is called when the player does it.
Anyways, it would have to be compiled into a function. When I tryed out something similar in the interactive interpreter (specifically:

```
def compile(code):
    def act():
       exec code
    return act
```

). This (which is would be more or less what would be in the final, with the exception of "code" being constructed by me) raised a odd error:

> File "", line 3 SyntaxError:
>   unqualified exec is not allowed in
>   function 'act' it is a nested
>   function.

How do I get around this?

Comment: You probably want to write your own parser using a lib like pyparsing.

Comment: What exactly does `code` hold? Your program worked fine for me, it did not give any such Syntax Error. Give an example of what string `code` can hold.

Comment: Try this [previous response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484872/in-python-why-doesnt-exec-work-in-a-function-with-a-subfunction). Looks like they had the same problem and solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484872/in-python-why-doesnt-exec-work-in-a-function-with-a-subfunction), is the lack of context. I wanted exec code in locals(), globals()