# Is it possible to call exec so that it's compatible with both Python 3 and Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm using the `exec` statement in some Python 2 code, and I'm trying to make that code compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3, but in Python 3, `exec` has changed from a statement into a function. Is it possible to write code that is compatible with both Python 2 and 3? I've read about [Python 2 and Python 3 dual development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11372190/4794), but I'm interested in specific solutions to the `exec` statement/function changes.

I realize that `exec` is generally discouraged, but I'm building an Eclipse plugin that implements live coding on top of PyDev. See the [project page](http://donkirkby.github.com/live-py-plugin/) for more details.

Comment: Read the book: http://python3porting.com/differences.html#exec

Comment: @LennartRegebro that source is wrong about `exec`

Comment: Huh, I'm pretty sure I tried that. Will try again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some [Python porting guides get the `exec`](http://python3porting.com/differences.html#exec) **wrong**:

> If you need to pass in the global or local dictionaries you will need to define a custom function with two different implementations, one for Python 2 and one for Python 3. As usual `six` includes an excellent implementation of this called `exec_()`.

**No such custom function is needed to port Python 2 code into Python 3** (*). You can do `exec(code)`, `exec(code, globs)` and `exec(code, globs, locs)` in Python 2, and it works.

Python has **always** accepted Python 3 compatible "syntax" for `exec` for as long that `exec` existed. The reason for this is that Python 2 and Python 1 (?!) have a hack to stay *backwards-compatible* with Python 0.9.8 in which `exec` was a function. Now, if `exec` is passed a 2-tuple, it is interpreted as `(code, globals)` and in case of a 3-tuple, it is interpreted as `(code, globals, locals)`. Yes, the [`exec_` in `six`](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/784c6a213c4527ea18f86a800f51bf16bc1df5bc/six.py?at=default#cl-688) is unnecessarily complicated.

Thus,

```
exec(source, global_vars, local_vars)
```

is guaranteed to work the same way in CPython 0.9.9, 1.x, 2.x, 3.x; and I have also verified that it works in Jython 2.5.2, PyPy 2.3.1 (Python 2.7.6) and IronPython 2.6.1:

```
Jython 2.5.2 (Release_2_5_2:7206, Mar 2 2011, 23:12:06) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.8.0_25
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exec('print a', globals(), {'a':42})
42
```

---

*) There are subtle differences so that not all *Python 3* code works in Python 2, namely

- `foo = exec` is valid in Python 3 but not in Python 2, and so is `map(exec, ['print(a + a)', 'print(b + b)'])`, but I really don't know any reason why anyone would want to use these constructs in real code.
- As found out by [Paul Hounshell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156767/hounshell), in Python 2, the following code will raise [SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'print_arg' because it contains a nested function with free variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41368813/918959):

  ```
  def print_arg(arg):
      def do_print():
          print(arg)
      exec('do_print()')
  ```

  The following construct works without exception.

  ```
  def print_arg(arg):
      def do_print():
          print(arg)
      exec 'do_print()' in {}
  ```

  Before Python 2.7.9, if one used `exec('do_print()', {})` for the latter instead, the same SyntaxError would have been thrown; but since Python 2.7.9 the parser/compiler would allow this alternate tuple syntax too.

Again, the solution in edge cases might be to forgo the use of `exec` and use `eval` instead ([`eval` can be used to execute bytecode that is compiled with `compile` in `exec` mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29456463/918959)):

```
def print_arg(arg):
    def do_print():
        print(arg)

    eval(compile('do_print(); print("it really works")', '<string>', 'exec'))
```

---

I have written a more detailed answer on internals of `exec`, `eval` and `compile` on [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python/29456463#29456463)

Comment: This isn't true if exec is in a function.  You get `SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'whatevs' it contains a nested function with free variables`

Comment: @Hounshell I added a disclaimer. However the original version of my answer states that "No such custom function is needed to port **Python 2** code into Python 3". That code didn't work in Python 2 to begin with; and needs a wrapper in Python 2 anyway.

Comment: But wouldn't `exec 'print "a"' in {}, {}` succeed in that situation in Python 2?  `exec('print "a"', {}, {})` throws the same exception.

Comment: I'm getting different results on different machines. Not sure if it's due to OS or Python version. http://pastebin.com/xgCjf8MT TL;DR: Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7.6 throws an error, OSX 10.11.6 with Python 2.7.10 does not.

Comment: But that isn't dual-compliant with Python3. `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` I think the only way to do something that is compliant across all three (<2.7.9, >= 2.7.9, > 3.0) is to use `eval`.  I tried my hand at that in a separate answer.

Answer (score 6):

I found several options for doing this, before Antti posted [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29876520/4794) that Python 2 supports the Python 3 [exec function syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement).

> The first expression may also be a tuple of length 2 or 3. In this case, the optional parts must be omitted. The form `exec(expr, globals)` is equivalent to `exec expr in globals`, while the form `exec(expr, globals, locals)` is equivalent to `exec expr in globals, locals`. The tuple form of exec provides compatibility with Python 3, where exec is a function rather than a statement.

If you don't want to use that for some reason, here are all the other options I found.

**Import Stubs**

You can declare two different import stubs and import whichever one works with the current interpreter. This is based on what I saw in the PyDev source code.

Here's what you put in the main module:

```
try:
    from exec_python2 import exec_code #@UnusedImport
except:
    from exec_python3 import exec_code #@Reimport
```

Here's what you put in `exec_python2.py`:

```
def exec_code(source, global_vars, local_vars):
    exec source in global_vars, local_vars
```

Here's what you put in `exec_python3.py`:

```
def exec_code(source, global_vars, local_vars):
    exec(source, global_vars, local_vars)
```

**Exec in Eval**

[Ned Batchelder](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200910/running_the_same_code_on_python_2x_and_3x.html) posted a technique that wraps the `exec` statement in a call to `eval` so it won't cause a syntax error in Python 3. It's clever, but not clear.

```
# Exec is a statement in Py2, a function in Py3

if sys.hexversion > 0x03000000:
    def exec_function(source, filename, global_map):
        """A wrapper around exec()."""
        exec(compile(source, filename, "exec"), global_map)
else:
    # OK, this is pretty gross.  In Py2, exec was a statement, but that will
    # be a syntax error if we try to put it in a Py3 file, even if it isn't
    # executed.  So hide it inside an evaluated string literal instead.
    eval(compile("""\
def exec_function(source, filename, global_map):
    exec compile(source, filename, "exec") in global_map
""",
    "<exec_function>", "exec"
    ))
```

**Six package**

The [six package](http://packages.python.org/six/) is a compatibility library for writing code that will run under both Python 2 and Python 3. It has an [`exec_()` function](http://packages.python.org/six/#six.exec_) that translates to both versions. I haven't tried it.

Comment: Six is awesome, you should give it a shot. Made the Python 3 porting I did much easier, and much less hacky (I'm looking at you, "Exec in Eval").

Comment: I was a little hesitant about adding a project dependency, @delnan. Do you just include some extra files in your project, or does anyone who uses your project need to install six as well?

Comment: In my case, I ported a build tool which bootstraps itself for installation, so dependencies were difficult (though there are some, they just aren't needed when bootstrapping), especially with six. So I ended up bundling it as a sub-module, which is permitted and was trivial except for `six.moves` (needs a one-line change, but still a change, and I didn't need it). You can see the changes in their entirety at https://github.com/paver/paver/pull/82 (don't be scared by the large number of changes, 90% of that is from a virtualenv bootstrap script and removing and adding bundled libraries).

Comment: @DonKirkby: You can either declare six a dependency in setup.py, meaning anyone who installs your module will automatically get six installed as well (assuming they use easy_install or pip or buildout, and they should). Or you can just put the six.py file in your module.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this, I couldn't use six, and my version of Python doesn't support @Antti's method because I used it in a nested function with free variables. I didn't want unnecessary imports either. Here's what I came up with.  This probably needs to be in the module, not in a method:

```
try:
  # Try Python2.
  _exec_impls = {
    0: compile('exec code', '<python2>', 'exec'),
    1: compile('exec code in _vars[0]', '<python2>', 'exec'),
    2: compile('exec code in _vars[0], _vars[1]', '<python2>', 'exec'),
  }

  def _exec(code, *vars):
    impl = _exec_impls.get(len(vars))
    if not impl:
      raise TypeError('_exec expected at most 3 arguments, got %s' % (len(vars) + 1))
    return eval(impl, { 'code': code, '_vars': vars })

except Exception as e:
  # Wrap Python 3.
  _exec = eval('exec')
```

Afterwards, `_exec` works like the Python3 version.  You can either hand it a string, or run it through `compile()`. It won't get the globals or locals you probably want, so pass them in:

```
def print_arg(arg):
  def do_print():
    print(arg)
  _exec('do_print(); do_print(); do_print()', globals(), locals())

print_arg(7)  # Prints '7'
```

Or not.  I'm a StackOverflow post, not a cop.

**Updates:**

Why don't you just use `eval()`?  `eval()` expects an *expression*, while `exec()` expects *statements*. If you've just got an expression it really doesn't matter what you use because all valid expressions are valid statements, but the converse is not true. Just executing a method is an expression, even if it doesn't return anything; there's an implied `None` returned.

This is demonstrated by trying to eval `pass`, which is a statement:

```
>>> exec('pass')
>>> eval('pass')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    pass
       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: except, of course, you don't need **`exec`** to execute the code... you can use `eval` instead, and it wouldn't be subject to these syntax errors

Comment: But `eval` doesn't allow multiple statements. This only uses `eval` to wrap up the `exec`. It's still `exec` that's running the code.  Updated answer to demonstrate a case where `eval` would fail.

Comment: see my answer on how to use `eval`.

Comment: I just tried your `do_print()` example with Python 2.7 and 3.5. They both worked fine with the built-in `exec()` and printed 7. No special `_exec()` needed. What didn't work for you?

Comment: Antti addressed it above. There was a change in 2.7.9, I was using 2.7.6