# Exec in Python 2.7.6

Tags: python, exec

I'm learning the basics of **eval**, **exec**, and **compile** on 2.7.6.

I have hit a roadblock on **exec**, as I get an error when running this:

```
exec 'print 5'
```

Error:

> SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'main' it
>   contains a nested function with free variables (EvalExecCompile.py,
>   line 61)

I have found that **exec** is an expression in 2.7.6 while a function in 3.x. Problem is, I cannot find a working example to learn from for **exec** in 2.7.6.

I am aware of all the dangers of using **exec**, etc., but just want to learn how to use them encase I ever need them.

Could someone please help? Maybe provide a working example that I can dissect?

Thank you.

The goal of my question is to learn how to use **exec** in 2.7.6 properly.

Comment: in 2.7.2 it works fine. `>>> exec "print 5"
5`

Comment: Thanks, that answer is what I needed. I really did search this to death before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use exec in a function that has a subfunction, unless you specify a context. From the docs:

> If exec is used in a function and the function contains a nested block
>   with free variables, the compiler will raise a SyntaxError unless the
>   exec explicitly specifies the local namespace for the exec. (In other
>   words, "exec obj" would be illegal, but "exec obj in ns (namespace)" would be
>   legal.)

Here is the code to implement `exec`:

```
def test2():
    """Test with a subfunction."""
    exec 'print "hi from test2"' in globals(), locals()
    def subfunction():
        return True

test2()
```

This example was taken from: [In Python, why doesn't exec work in a function with a subfunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484872/in-python-why-doesnt-exec-work-in-a-function-with-a-subfunction)

Comment: Actually, this whole answer was taken from another answer on the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4484946/2555451

Comment: i have modified the answer to meet this questions requirement. I have also mentioned clearly where this answer was taken from. In the past when i pasted links, i used to get comments saying i should paste the most relavent part.

Comment: That doesn't mean it is OK to copy/paste an existing answer, even if you give attribution.  Linking to another answer should be to give support your *own* answer.  You just posted the exact same text again over here (and threw out a few words).

Comment: I'm back on the Python road with exec. Thanks all.

Comment: After understanding the answer, I began to understand what was being shown at another site. Specifically, you can define your own namespace and then use exec withing it. '>>> code = compile('a = 1 + 2', '<string>', 'exec')
>>> ns = {}'
>>> exec code in ns
>>> print ns['a']
3         [link](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/)