# How to restart Python script with subfunctions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a massive Python script that needs to be restarted automatically when it breaks. When I try a standard approach by wrapping the script into a function and then calling it via `while True`, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'wrappedFunc' because it contains a nested function with free variables
```

As I understand, this is due to the fact that my main script has sub functions. Can I still do it somehow via Python or should this be done in Windows via a batch file?

Comment: It sounds like you should eliminate the `exec`s.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Are you in a position to upgrade to Python 3? Apparently if you do, [this error won't occur.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41368813/953482)

Comment: @Kevin Unfortunately, not.

Comment: @Kevin: But the reason the error won't occur is that Python 3 no longer tries to support assigning to function locals inside `exec`. Such assignments are now basically undefined behavior and mostly don't work (there are some caveats), so there would just be other errors.

Comment: Ok, you caught me: I was just trying to increase Python 3 adoption rates without actually addressing the underlying problem ;-)

Comment: Exec should be avoided anyway. What exactly are you doing with it?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I use it to grab the content of my SQL files and save it as strings with the names the same as files names `exec (query_name + " = data")`.

Comment: As others have said, you should use a dict instead.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Do I understand it right that if I take this route, I will create not variables but dictionary entries? So in my example instead of calling variable `query_name`, I would have to call `my_dict[query_name]`?

Comment: Yes. That is the correct approach for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to using the `exec` keyword inside a function that has subfunctions. Python needs you to explicitly determine which scope the `exec` will use to run in this case.

Comment: My main script has this code `exec (query_name + " = data")`. So what do you suggest I do with this?

Comment: @sprogissd: Use a dict.

Comment: @user2357112 Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @sprogissd: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Answer (score 0):

exec command: `execfile('file.py')`. Insecure and kind of hack hacky. Avoid wherever possible.
Spawn a shell process: `os.system('python file.py')`. Use when desperate.

*PS: i haven't tried it to invoke/run same file*