# How can I get rid of using exec when getting variables from a yaml file

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a configuration file that contains some queries like these:

```
query = 'column_a in @certain_variable'
```

and variables:

```
variables:
  certain_variable = ["val1","val2"]
  certain_variable2 = ["val1","val2"]
  ... more
```

And the way I am doing it now is:

```
for k, v in variables.items():
    exec (k + '=v')

df.query(query)
```

Because I don't see another way of making available variables from the yaml file to pandas.

The reason I am trying to remove exec is because I have some subfunctions that leads to errors (as described here: [Why doesn't exec work in a function with a subfunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484872/why-doesnt-exec-work-in-a-function-with-a-subfunction))

Comment: Have you tried passing your dict to query? eg: `df.query(query, local_dict=variables)` ?

Comment: @JonClements thank you, that works.