# Workaround for subfunction defined in exec() inside of a function

Tags: python, exec

I am writing a function that needs to contain a subfunction in order to run the `curve_fit` function from the `scipy.optimize` module. The issue is that the number of variables that goes into the subfunction (let's call it `fitFunc`) depends on how many columns are in the dataframe input into the main function. Below is my code:

```py
def function(mod_data):
    import numpy as np
    i = 0
    ps = len(mod_data.columns) - 7
    temp = '(xdat[0]**b)'

    while i != (ps-1):
        dummypy = '(xdat[' + str(i+1) + ']'
        temp = temp + '+' + dummypy + '**b)'
        i += 1

    xdat = mod_data.iloc[:,7:].values
    xdat = np.transpose(xdat)
    ydat = mod_data.iloc[:,1].values

    form = 'def fitFunc(xdat, a, b): return (a/ps) * (%s)' % temp
    exec(form)
    result = curve_fit(fitFunc, xdat, ydat, 
                       p0 = np.array([100000,.75]))
    return result
```

Above `mod_data` is the dataframe that contains the variables for the modeling process. `form` should be the following character string if `xdat` has two or three rows respectively:

```
# xdat has 2 rows
form = 'def fitFunc(xdat, a, b): return (a/ps) * ((xdat[0]**b)+(xdat[1]**b))'

# xdat has 3 rows
form = 'def fitFunc(xdat, a, b): return (a/ps) * ((xdat[0]**b)+(xdat[1]**b)+(xdat[2]**b))'
```

I realize that I could just define the function, but the issue is that I don't know how many variables will actually be in the dataframe before it's entered into the function, so I run through the final columns in order to find that number, then write have the code write the function for me depending on how many variables there will be.

I know from this previous question that `exec` doesn't work when there are subfunctions in the function: [Why doesn't exec work in a function with a subfunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484872/why-doesnt-exec-work-in-a-function-with-a-subfunction) . So my goal here is to find another way to define the `fitFunc` subfunction depending on how many variables `xdat` will have from the `mod_data` dataframe. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create the function dynamically and use `exec`. Just iterate over `xdat`.

```
def fitFunc(xdat, a, b):
    return (a/ps) * sum(x**b for x in xdat)
```