# there must be a better way to do this

Tags: python

This is an ugly, high maintenance factory.  I really just need a way to use the string to instantiate an object with a name that matches the string.  I think metaclass is the answer but I can't figure out how to apply it:

```
from commands.shVersionCmd import shVersionCmd
from commands.shVRFCmd import shVRFCmd
def CommandFactory(commandnode):
    if commandnode.attrib['name'] == 'shVersionCmd': return shVersionCmd(commandnode)        
    if commandnode.attrib['name'] == 'shVRFCmd': return shVRFCmd(commandnode)
```

Comment: Maybe you would like to change the title to "Call function by name"? And maybe you can try to google this then? ;)

Comment: I may have had a research-fail, but I can say with confidence it wasn't for lack of trying.  Thanks for the keyword hints though:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up global names with the `globals()` function, which returns a dict:

```
from commands.shVersionCmd import shVersionCmd
from commands.shVRFCmd import shVRFCmd

# An explicit list of allowed commands to prevent malicious activity.
commands = ['shVersionCmd', 'shVRFCmd']

def CommandFactory(commandnode):
    cmd = commandnode.attrib['name']
    if cmd in commands:
        fn = globals()[cmd]
        fn(commandnode)
```

Comment: One problem with this solution: If `cmd` it *not* in `commands`, it just returns without raising an exception. Easy to fix, but as easy to miss. And you need to add a `return` before `fn(commandnode)`.

Comment: True, but the same is true of the originally shown code.  I didn't want to invent a behavior for that case.

Comment: Just confirming:  It doesn't matter that shVersionCmd and shVRFCdm are classes (not functions,) , right?  thanks for this.  I haven't seen globals used before.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is your friend:

```
from commands import *
def CommandFactory(commandnode):
    name=commandnode.attrib['name']
    assert name in ( "shVersionCmd", "shVRFCmd" ), "illegal command"
    return eval(name+"."+name)(commandnode)
```

Note that if you are *sure* that `name` will never contain any illegal commands, you *could* remove the `assert` and turn the function into a no-maintenance-delight. In case of doubt, leave it in and maintain the list in a single place.

Comment: eval is rarely a good idea, and introduces vulnerabilites into your program.

Comment: So, show us *your* solution. `eval` is a feature and yes, it might be dangerous. That doesn't mean it's useless. And you make it sound as if it *always* introduces vulnerabilities, but that is not true, it depends on the source of `commandnode.attrib['name']`.

Comment: No, it's not useless, but it's a big blunt hammer that is easy to overuse.  `globals()` would be enough here.

Answer (score 0):

This answer [How to make an anonymous function in Python without Christening it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629876/how-to-make-an-anonymous-function-in-python-without-christening-it) discusses how to cleanly call blocks of code based on a key

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference would be to turn the dependencies between the factory and the command implementations around, so that each command registers itself with the factory.

Example implementation:

File commands/__init__.py:

```
import pkgutil
import commands

_commands = {}

def command(commandCls):
    _commands[commandCls.__name__] = commandCls
    return commandCls

def CommandFactory(commandnode):
    name = commandnode.attrib['name']
    if name in _commands.keys():
        return _commands[name](commandnode)

# Load all commands
for loader, module_name, is_pkg in  pkgutil.walk_packages(commands.__path__):
    if module_name!=__name__:
        module = loader.find_module(module_name).load_module(module_name)
```

File commands/mycommand.py:

```
from commands import command

@command
class MyCommand(object):    
    def __init__(self, commandnode):
        pass
```

Small test:

```
from commands import CommandFactory

# Stub node implementation
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.attrib = { "name": name }

if __name__=='__main__':
    cmd = CommandFactory(Node("MyCommand"))
    assert cmd.__class__.__name__=="MyCommand", "New command is instance of MyCommand"
    cmd = CommandFactory(Node("UnknownCommand"))
    assert cmd is None, "Returns None for unknown command type"
```