# How to execute Python program and get the variables using exec()?

Tags: python, exec, python-3.3

I want to execute a correct Python program using `exec()` and then get variables and their values after executing. Google says that I should create a dictionary and write the result of execution there: `exec(code_object)` in variables. But unfortunately that doesn't in Python 3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Behaviour of exec function in Python 2 and Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behaviour-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3)

Answer (score 1):

The code in Python 3 should be:

```
exec(code_object, variables)
```

This syntax is also [Python 2 compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29456463/918959).

---

```
exec(code_object) in variables
```

would *compile* and run in Python 3 but do something completely different from Python 2 - it would execute the `code_object` in current scope; the `exec` would return `None`; then the expression `None in variables` would evaluate `False` since `None` is not a key in `variables`; the result would be dropped - thus neither compile time nor possibly run-time error occurs, except for `code_object` seeing the wrong scope.