# what is the difference between eval and exec in python?

Tags: python, exec, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between eval, exec, and compile in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python)

I known that

1. eval is a `function`
2. exec is a `statement`

And the simple usage of both is :

```
eval('1+2')
exec 'print 1+2'
```

But there are other usages that I can't understand.

1. Using a variable to store a function name, and using this variable to
   call the function
   eg:

   ```
   def test():
       print 'hello world'
   func = 'test'
   func = eval(func)
   func() # this will call test()
   ```

   I type(func) after
   `func = eval(func)`
   it returns
   `<type 'function'>`
   I read the document of `eval`, but I don't known why the eval can do
   this.
2. Using a variable to store a module name, and using this variable to import the module.
   eg.

   ```
   m = 'sys'
   exec "import " +　m
   ```

   Is this the reason:
   `import module_name` is a statement, not expression?
   and:
   `eval` does only to calculate a expression
   `exec` does to run the statement in the str?

Comment: @avasal hello, I have seen this article, but I don't know the two examples im my question, you can see it.

Comment: @TankyWoo To add a new line add two spaces and start writing from the next line. :)

Comment: This questions asks about advanced usage of eval/exec which is not even mentioned in the proposed duplicate and it's examples, so it is NOT a duplicate, just way more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part of your question about storing the function name can be explained by the fact that this would be equivalent:

```
def test():
    print 'hello world'
func = test
func() # this will call test()
```

The call to `eval()` in your example is no different than a call like:

```
y = eval('x + 1')
```

I believe your second question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python), and the answers might be helpful.

Comment: But I don't know how `func = eval(func)` can make a str to function type?