# python: How do I dynamically create bound methods from user supplied source code?

Tags: python, dynamically-generated

I would like to construct a class in python that supports dynamic updating of methods from user supplied source code.

Instances of class `Agent` have a method `go`. At the time an instance is constructed, its `.go()` method does nothing. For example, if we do `a=Agent()`, and then `a.go()` we should get a `NotImplementedError` or something like that. The user then should be able to interactively define `a.go()` by supplying source code. A simple source code example would be

mySourceString = `"print('I learned how to go!')"`

which would be injected into `a` like this
`a.update(mySourceString)`

Further invokations of `a.go()` would then result in `"I learned how to go!"` being printed to the screen.

I have partially figured out how to do this with the following code:

```
import types

class Error(Exception):
    """Base class for exceptions in this module."""
    pass

class NotImplementedError(Error):
    pass

class Agent(object):
    def go(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def update(self,codeString):
        #Indent each line of user supplied code
        codeString = codeString.replace('\n','\n    ')
        #Turn code into a function called func
        exec "def func(self):\n"+'    '+codeString
        #Make func a bound method on this instance
        self.go = types.MethodType(func, self)
```

QUESTIONS

1. Is this implementation sensible?
2. Will this implementation incur unexpected scope issues?
3. Is there an obvious way to sandbox the user supplied code to prevent it from touching external objects? I can think of ways to do this by supplying sets of allowed external objects, but this seems not pythonic.

Possibly useful SO posts

1. [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python)
2. [Adding a Method to an Existing Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object)

(I am working in python 2.6)

Comment: Can't the go method just delegate to a hidden internal method?

Comment: Sure but the whole game is to dynamically construct that method from user provided source...

Comment: My point is that it might be beneficial to add a layer of indirection, and swap out the source of the layer below. That way, if I make a reference to `Agent.go` somewhere in my code (`foo = Agent.go`), then it will still call the most recent code from the user when I call foo at a later date.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. this is a good idea. Thank you.

Any other commends regarding implementation?

Comment: Note: there *already* is a [`NotImplementedError` exception](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NotImplementedError). No need to define it yourself.

Comment: Sandboxing is hard. I can easily get hold of external objects: `(1).__class__.__bases__[0].__subclasses__()` gets me a list of every class in the interpreter

Comment: honestly I would almost recommend using ply or something to define your own language and have them write their code in that (It could be just a limited subset of python even) that way you can parse your language code back into python and hopefully prevent unwanted behaviors