# What is the main use of the Python built-in 'compile'?

Tags: python, compilation, built-in

When looking through the list of [Python built-in](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) functions, I struggle with understanding the usefulness the method [`compile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile).  All of the examples I could find point to a simple "hello world".  It make sense *what* it does, but not *when* to use it.

Is this the same method Python uses to generate the .pyc files?

Can this be used to remove some of the dynamic nature of Python to improve performance on certain blocks of code? (Knowing full well that a module in C is the way to go precompiled modules.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From here: [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python):

`compile` is a lower level version of `exec` and `eval`. It does not execute or evaluate your statements or expressions, but returns a code object that can do it. The modes are as follows:

1. `compile(string, '', 'eval')` returns the code object that would have been executed had you done `eval(string)`. Note that you *cannot* use statements in this mode; only a (single) expression is valid.
2. `compile(string, '', 'exec')` returns the code object that would have been executed had you done `exec(string)`. You can use any number of statements here.
3. `compile(string, '', 'single')` is like the `exec` mode, but it will ignore everything except for the first statement. Note that an `if`/`else` statement with its results is considered a single statement.

UPDATE:

***When to compile Python?***

Generally you compile Python to take advantage of performance. Compiled code has a much faster startup time since it doesn't have to be compiled, but **it doesn't run any faster**.

Most notably, you would use `compile` if you want to **convert code into bytecode by hand**. This brings up another important, but pertinent question **why** do this?

As referenced in this [magnificent article](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/):

> if you want to use exec and you plan on executing that code more than
>   once, make sure you compile it into bytecode first and then execute
>   that bytecode only and only in a new dictionary as namespace.

Of particular note is this:

> Now how much faster is executing bytecode over creating bytecode and
>   executing that?:
>
> $ python -mtimeit -s 'code = "a = 2; b = 3; c = a * b"' 'exec code'
>   10000 loops, best of 3: 22.7 usec per loop
>
> $ python -mtimeit -s 'code = compile("a = 2; b = 3; c = a * b",
>   "", "exec")' 'exec code' 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.765 usec
>   per loop
>
> **32 times as fast for a very short code example.** It becomes a lot worse
>   the more code you have. Why is that the case? **Because parsing Python
>   code and converting that into Bytecode is an expensive operation
>   compared to evaluating the bytecode.** That of course also affects
>   `execfile` which totally does not use bytecode caches, how should it.
>   It's not gonna magically check if there is a `.pyc` file if you are
>   passing the path to a `foo.py` file.

Comment: This is what I have gathered as to what it does, but it's still not clear on when / why to use it.  The only thing that comes to mind would a quick check to see if there are any syntax error prior to calling an 'eval' / 'exec'.

Comment: @AdamLewis, my apologies. Updated.

Comment: Great update.  I had a hunch that it was geared towards only really being useful when using the `exec` built-in.  Thanks for taking the time to shed some light on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the dynamic nature thing, no, not really. The resulting code object is still interpreted; the same bytecode still runs.

The most useful/impressive use of compile() (and code generation) that I've seen is in Jinja2. It actually generates Python code from your templates, then uses compile so it runs at 'native' (== interpreter) speed, if that makes sense.

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/jinja2/environment.py#L506

In contrast with, say, django.template, which does variable lookups, etc in "userspace" (again, so to speak - metaphor is kind of weird).

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/base.py#L752

Comment: I've used django and jinja both, but never dug that deep into the template system before.  I agree that that's pretty way to process the templates.  Maybe this is part of the reason I've used jinga as the templating system in django :)