# Why is eval('pass') a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, eval

I was trying to temporarily null out a string I was passing to `eval` to do nothing (I didn't remove it because preserving the order was important for my hacky profile script), and was somewhat miffed that when I gave it `'pass'` it dumped on me, likewise with an empty string or some equivalent do-nothing statement.

```
>>> eval('pass')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    pass
       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I eventually just fed it `None`, but why was it a syntax error?  "Unexpected EOF" perplexes me; the string is a complete statement in-and-of-itself.  Does `eval` not tolerate keywords?

Comment: `eval` tolerates keywords: `eval('lambda x: x')` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Note that `exec('pass')` is valid. The way I remember the difference in `exec` and `eval` is that you use `eval` for anything that return something (including `None`.) You use `exec` for anything that does not return anything. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python for some good examples.

Comment: `pass` is not an expression, it's a statement -- so use `exec()` instead of `eval()` or give `eval()` an expression. `None` is an expression.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting from [eval's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

> The *expression* argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression.

Then, `pass` is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: +1 Indeed, [`pass` *is* a statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass)