# Doubts about the strange Python API

Tags: python

Just now , I read  a piece of code which was written in Python,  I feel very doubtful to some python native API.  the code as following:

```
filename = os.path.join(self.root_path, filename)
d = imp.new_module('config')
d.__file__ = filename
try:
    with open(filename) as config_file:
        exec(compile(config_file.read(), filename, 'exec'), d.__dict__)
except IOError as e:
    if silent and e.errno in (errno.ENOENT, errno.EISDIR):
        return False
    e.strerror = 'Unable to load configuration file (%s)' % e.strerror
    raise
```

I have two doubts about the code ,please help to answer them.

**doubt 1.**

```
compile(config_file.read(), filename, 'exec')
```

What's the functions about the compile function's second argument  **filename** ?

**doubt 2.**

```
exec(compile(config_file.read(), filename, 'exec'), d.__dict__)
```

What's the functions about the exec function's second argument  **d.__dict__** ?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `compile` and `eval` functions are builtin to the Python interpreter. You should read [their documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) online. These seem to be the relevant bits for your questions:

Regarding `compile`'s `filename` parameter:

> The `filename` argument should give the file from which the code was read; pass some recognizable value if it wasn’t read from a file (`'<string>'` is commonly used).

Regarding `exec`'s `globals` parameter:

> If only `globals` is provided, it must be a dictionary, which will be used for both the global and the local variables.