# Is there a way to import an object from python module programatically?

Tags: python

Assume you have module foo and object bar. Usually you simply import object from module by  doing:

```
from foo import bar
```

this is simple and straightforward. 
I want to accomplish same thing programatically. Name of the object "bar" is provided by the user, and can be some arbitrary value, so I need something like:

```
eval("from foo import %s" % ("bar"))
```

I'd just like to get a way to accomplish this. For some reason:

```
eval("from string import lower")
```

gives me syntaxerror.

I'm aware of some security consideration here (someone may import something stupid etc, break stuff etc). For the time being we can leave security consideration aside. I just want to import object from module and use this object later. Assuming the module name is string and the object I need to get is function lower() I need something like this:

```
import imp
f, filename, rest = imp.find_module("string")
my_module = imp.load_module("string", f, filename, rest)
object_i_need = my_module.load_object_from_module("lower", my_module)
object_i_need("HALLO") # should return "hallo"
```

Third line is missing at the moment, there is no load_object_from_module function, or I haven't found it yet.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: `getattr(my_module, "lower")`. But you should better use `importlib` module.

Comment: You're looking for getattr() to get attributes from the module given the name as a string...

Comment: @Ashvini yeah getattr is the right answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14000967/2015686

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary you can publish your comment as answer I will accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__import__` with Ashwini's idea:

```
module = __import__("foo")
obj = getattr(module, "bar")
```

See `__import__` reference [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__).

**Edit:** As pointed by @LukasGraf is better practice use [importlib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).

```
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module("foo")
obj = getattr(module, "bar")
```

Comment: You should use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module), not `__import__`, unless you handle namespace packages yourself.

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for the `exec` statement. Brackets are optional, and it works with string formatting and concatenation, so all of the following work:

```
exec "from string import lower"            # Works
exec "from string import %s" % ("lower")   # Also works

exec("from string import lower")           # Also works
exec("from string import %s" % ("lower"))  # Also works

obj = "lower"
exec "from string import " + obj           # Also works
exec("from string import " + obj)          # Also works
```

`Eval` only takes an expression, not a statement, and `import` is a statement in python. For more on the difference between the two, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220790/3681392

For more on the difference between expressions and statements, read the python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html or search SO, there are plenty of questions about the difference.