# How to use out 'exec()' command in python

Tags: python, exec

For the code below:

```
command = '\'{:.' + str(3) + 'f}\'.format(' + str(12.6543423) + ')'

print(command)
print('{:.3f}'.format(12.6543423))
print(exec(command))
```

**Expected results:**

```
'{:.3f}'.format(12.6543423)
12.654
12.654
```

**Actual results:**

```
'{:.3f}'.format(12.6543423)
12.654
None
```

Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? I'm both trying to write a number rounding function and trying to understand the exec command.

Comment: did you mean eval? have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python

Comment: *sigh*: there's no need to use exec or eval at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eval`.

```
>>> eval('\'{:.' + str(3) + 'f}\'.format(' + str(12.6543423) + ')')
'12.654'
```

Comment: Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html?highlight=ast.literal_eval#ast.literal_eval) instead [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval)

Comment: @MauroBaraldi Concatenation using + isn't included within that,from the doc *The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.* and if i am wrong then help me in that. I would love to know.

Comment: The `+` operation is not a "feature" of eval. Python first concatenates the strings and only then passes a single string to eval. That is of course the case with all function calls (in every programming language)...

Comment: @MauroBaraldi: did you try `literal_eval`? It won't work for this case, because `literal_eval` won't invoke `format` for you.  It won't call any functions, that's the whole point, to avoid code execution.

Answer (score 9):

Or don't use exec or eval at all. Use the features `format` offers:

```
>>> '{:.{}f}'.format(12.6543423, 3)
12.654
```

Comment: Ah, thank you - wasn't aware that you could have curly brackets within curly brackets, probably should have tried that first. Thanks. Even so, I'm keeping the current answer ticked, because I was also curious to learn about eval() and exec().

Comment: @JakeLevi learning about eval and exec is good.  One of the most important things to learn about them is that they are really really blunt instruments that you almost never need.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) instead of `exec()` to get the result returned by a expression.

Comment: Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html?highlight=ast.literal_eval#ast.literal_eval) instead [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval)

Comment: @MauroBaraldi: did you try `literal_eval`? It won't work for this case, because `literal_eval` won't invoke `format` for you.  It won't call any functions, that's the whole point, to avoid code execution.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use exec

```
command = '\'{:.' + str(3) + 'f}\'.format(' + str(12.6543423) + ')'
print(command)
mycode = """print('{:.3f}'.format(12.6543423))"""

print('{:.3f}'.format(12.6543423))
exec(mycode)
```

Comment: it does not. i would also use eval() instead. but it is still usable with exec(). There is in my opinion a lot of confusion regarding exec, also some changes from python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing exec and eval:

```
In [27]: command = 'print'+'('+'\'{:.' + str(3) + 'f}\'.format(' + str(12.6543423) + ')'+')'

In [28]: exec(command)
12.654
```