# Python3 exec, why returns None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, exec

When the code below this text, and returns the result None why?

```
with open('exx.py', 'rb') as file:
ff = compile(file.read(), 'exx.py', 'exec')
snip_run = exec(ff, locals())
if 'result' in locals():
    print(snip_run, result)
else:
    print(snip_run)
```

Result:

```
777777
None
```

Module code exx.py:

```
print('777777')
```

Comment: Try print( print('777777') )

Comment: `None` as opposed to... what? What were you expecting? As it stands, that's not even valid syntax.

Comment: Returns the same thing: print(exec(open ( 'exx.py').read()))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem of course is not only that `print` returns `None`, it is that [exec returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29456463/918959), always.

```
>>> exec('42') is None
True
```

If you'd need the return value, you'd use `eval`:

```
>>> eval('42')
42
```

after which you'd notice that `print` still returns `None`...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all decided as follows:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def stdoutIO(stdout=None):
    old = sys.stdout
    if stdout is None:
        stdout = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = stdout
    yield stdout
    sys.stdout = old


with stdoutIO() as s:
    with open('exx.py', 'rb') as file:
        ff = compile(file.read(), 'exx.py', 'exec')
        exec(ff, locals())
        if 'result' in locals():
            sys.stdout.write(locals().get('result'))

print(s.getvalue())
```

Answer (score -1):

Print always returns none.

Also this is not how you should ever execute code from another module. That's what import is for.

Comment: Thank you for exactly what you want!)
And you can make the print () does not return None?