# Why does `print(exec(...))` return `None`?

Tags: python

input:-

```
x = '''
def fun(x, y):
  print(x+y) 

a = int(input('enter the value of a: '))
b = int(input('enter the value of b: '))

fun(a, b)
'''

print(exec(x))
```

output:-

```
enter the value of a: 5
enter the value of b: 5
10
None
```

Comment: I guess the ‘None’ comes from ‘exec()’ which you print. So just call the ‘exec()’

Comment: If you want to get rid of the None you can just print the result inside x and not doing print(exec(x)) but only exec(x)  and print what you want inside

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 exec, why returns None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592588/python3-exec-why-returns-none)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `None` doesn't come from *nowhere*, that's the return value of the `exec` method and as you `print` it, so it shows up

Just do

```
x = '''
def fun(x, y):
  print(x+y) 
a = int(input('enter the value of a: '))
b = int(input('enter the value of b: '))
fun(a, b)
'''

exec(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

As @azro said, the `None` is the return value from the `exec` method.

However, if you want to retrieve the result from `fun` inside a variable `res`, you can do:

```py
x = '''
def fun(x, y):
  return x + y
 
a = int(input('enter the value of a: '))
b = int(input('enter the value of b: '))
res = fun(a, b)
'''
exec(x)

print(res)  # prints the sum of the 2 numbers you gave
```