# How to run strings as a command in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I added two strings together and now I want to use those strings to create multiple dataframes.... I currently have:

```
filepath = 'C:/........GC results/lng_11169_fid00'

l = []

for i in range(1,7):
    newpath = filepath + str(i)
    l.append(newpath)

print l 



d =[]

for i in range(1,7):
    dataframes = "df" + str(i)
    d.append(dataframes)
print d
enter code here



m = []
dfstr = "pd.DataFrame.from_csv("

for i in d:
    for x in l:
        newdf =  i + "="+ dfstr + x + ", index_col = None)"
        m.append(newdf)
print m
```

out:

```
['df1=pd.DataFrame.from_csv(C:...lng_11169_fid001, index_col = None)', 'df2=pd.DataFrame.from_csv(C:...lng_11169_fid002, index_col = None)'..... + 20 others]
```

I want to use those strings to make a DataFrame. Is this possible?

Comment: You will find [this information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python) useful.

Comment: @Trimax but this is about calling an internal Python command, isn't it?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan You're all right.  He wants to execute code dinamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```py
list_ = ['df1=pd.DataFrame.from_csv(C:...lng_11169_fid001, index_col = None)', 'df2=pd.DataFrame.from_csv(C:...lng_11169_fid002, index_col = None)'..... + 20 others]

for code_ in list_:
     exec code_
```

Comment: `exec` is a potentially dangerous command to call, I wouldn't just suggest someone use it without explaining what it does.

Comment: This does not work in python3 either, you need to do - `exec(code_)`

Answer (score 1):

An XY problem... Is this what you want? Simply write executable code instead of string concatenation.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
path_pattern = 'C:/........GC results/lng_11169_fid00*'
files = glob.glob(path_pattern)
dataframes = [pd.DataFrame.from_csv(f, index_col=None) for f in files]
print dataframes[0]  # yours df1
```

Comment: Will this find _fid_001 to _012? and then create a dataframe from each csv?

Comment: Yes it does.. Many thanks for this simple yet powerful answer!