# python exec() with an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find a way to exec() an if statement.

So, for example:

```
exampleCode = "if 0 < 1:"

exec(exampleCode)
    print("Zero is less than one")
```

Now, obviously this isn't possible with exec(). But is it with something similar?

Something else that would work would be:

```
exampleCode = "if 0 < 1:"

exampleCode
    print("Zero is less than one")
```

Again, this isn't possible, because variables cannot be code.

So, again, is there something *else* that may work?

Comment: Just use a lambda. You're aware that exec/eval are considered harmful and there are other ways to do this?

Comment: As I understand it, they're harmful due to possible exploitation of user input, but in the actual code I'm using it in, the user input is not what is used. Instead, a good example would be that they choose from a list of what code they want to be used, getting rid of this risk.

Comment: PieCrust: perhaps, but there are much less tortured ways of doing that. That's just a switch statement (Pythonic idiom: use a dict whose values return expressions) or if/elif/else ladder.

Comment: Here is **[How to implement a switch statement using a dict in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374239/why-doesnt-python-have-a-switch-statement/374276)**

Comment: Near-duplicate of [**What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile in Python?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python), which already has good complete answers.

Comment: @smci I would say not duplicate because the intent of this question seems to be about, in essence, using templates in python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this, sort of, with `eval`:

```
exampleCode = "0 < 1"
if eval(exampleCode):
    print("Zero is less than one")
```

...but it's unclear what the benefit is of doing this (that is, there's something you're not showing us that motivates your question).

Comment: Doesn't `eval()` return the result of code? How would this work?

Comment: The `eval()` function returns the result of parsing and evaluating the given expression represented as a string. It works because that's what `eval()` does.

Comment: Greg, keeping @PieCrust's `exampleCode` as it is, I think that it is better to remove the `if` and the `:` (which reduces to your `exampleCode` variable) and then continue your method, which is, using `eval`. (Just an idea)

Comment: Exactly. And `0 < 1` isn't a function.

Comment: The string `"0 < 1"` is not a function, it's an *expression*, and that is what `eval()` evaluates.

Comment: Sorry for accepting this answer two years late, I guess I forgot about it..? Anyway, I don't remember why I asked, but I can guess, and I think this response best addresses my question and the intent behind it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) (an anonymous function). We can pass an arbitrary lambda which allows dynamically evaluating a condition in the scope in which it is evaluated:

```
# 1) A lambda with 0 args; this is silly because it will always evluate to a constant
cond_0args = lambda: 0 < 1
# <function <lambda> at 0x1084ffc80>

# 2) A lambda with 2 args:
cond = lambda x, y: x<y

# ... you could of course have a lambda with 3 args or whatever
#cond = lambda x, y, z: some_expression_involving_x_y_z

if cond_0args():
    print("Zero is less than one")
```

or, more sensibly:

```
if cond(0,1):
    print("Zero is less than one")
```

Comment: See, this seems to work, but why, since _`0 < 1` isn't a full function?_

Comment: PieCrust: yes it is, **Python lambda functions don't use `return`, they're just an expression**. @MotokoKusanagi: yes it is an answer. We pass an arbitrary lambda which allows dynamically evaluating a condition in the scope in which it is evaluated.

Comment: @MotokoKusanagi it is a solution to my problem, and if it is not an answer to my question, then I phrased my question wrong.

Comment: PieCrust: don't appear to agree with him. He's wrong, and it is an answer to the question. Flagged his comment as unconstructive, which it is. (If he said he didn't understand why it was an answer, and asked that, that would be different...)

Comment: But they `return`, still, even without the declaration, no?

Comment: PieCrust: don't get hung up on *"it can't be a proper function if it doesn't have a return keyword"*. All a function is, is a language construct for computing an expression. All a lambda is, is an unnamed function. Python lambdas don't use a return statement. No big deal.

Comment: Since I don't have enough reputation to move this to chat, can you?

Comment: It wouldn't let me automatically either: "Pie Crust has only 18 reputation, not yet enough to chat". I had to manually create a **chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/80619/discussion-about-python-lambdas-eval-exec-and-switch-statements?tab=general**

Comment: I can't actually use chats we'll just have to continue here.

Comment: I think I'm thinking about lambdas wrong. In my mind, they are functions without names: You put in a value, and one comes out. So, since `0 < 1` takes no value, and has no output, how is it a valid lambda?

Comment: @Pie Crust:  It does produce output.  It returns `true`, since 0 is less than 1. And in the same way that `def fn():` doesn't take any arguments, neither does that lambda.  Note that you can also create lambdas that do take arguments: `lambda z: z < 1`

Comment: I've actually got to go. I'll try to research more & understand, but if I don't, I'll be posting in these comments (if that's ok with you)

Comment: Aha! I got it now! So they just _calculate_ an expression and then return the result. Which means the code we were using just said `if true, print("blah")`! Thank you so much, I understand now, _and_ I think I'll be able to use this in my program. Cheers!

Comment: Right, just the evaluation of the expression is deferred.

Comment: @smci Hello! I am working on almost exactly the same problem, and my question is: If we are given a string of `exampleCode = "0 < 1"` how can we construct the `lambda` using the `exampleCode ` but not the `0 < 1` directly. Defining `cond = lambda: exampleCode ` and then calling `if cond(): print("Zero is less than one")` doesn't work.

Comment: @FatihAkici: `"0 < 1"` is not an expression, but a string containing an expression, so your lambda would need to `eval(cond_str)`. Anyway turns out this is a near-duplicate of [**What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile in Python?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python)

Comment: Lambdas are anonymous functions. Like regular functions, they defer evaluating their args until they're evaluated, and in the scope in which they are evaluated. `0 < 1` totally has a value, just as much as `2 + 3` ! That's all there is to it... read more about lambdas in doc or here on SO...

Answer (score 0):

Python has to know the syntactical role of every line of code when it compiles a block. Allowing things like what you're trying to do causes a lot of complications, because there could be things like

```
line = random.choice(['if flag:', '    print(1)'])

flag = True
for i in range(5):
    print(1)
exec(random.choice(['if flag:', '    print(1)'])) # What indentation level is this?
    print(2) # Is this part of the loop?
```

If you want to do what you're trying to do, you'll have to make the whole block a string and `exec` it, with the part that changes from run to run substituted in:

```
template = '''\
{statement}
    print("Zero is less than one")'''

exec(statement.format('if 0 < 1:'))
```

Using `exec` at all is generally a bad idea, though.

Comment: Again, since the users won't be able to directly input code to be `exec()`uted, I see no risk.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with Python to understand your code, so I'll leave it, since other solutions seem to work.

Comment: @PieCrust: This answer isn't about risk; it's about how you can't really define exec in such a way that exec-ing a control statement makes sense. (The part at the end is about risk a little, but it's more that if you're using `exec`, you're usually thinking in terms of "what code would I type for each case" instead of more useful ways to think about your problems.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a sort of quiz program with questions like "What piece of code goes here" (at least that is what I got from your comments) than a dictionary would work fine:

```
answers = {1: (True, 'if 0 < 1:') 2: (False, '...'}
answer = input('what code goes here?')
for k, v in answers:
    print('{} - {}'.format(k, v[1])

if answers[answer][0]:
    print('correct')
else:
    print('incorrect')
```

Comment: This is just a switch statement implemented in Python as a dict, as I already suggested above in comments.

Comment: No, that was just an example to explain easily without having to talk about my entire program when this is jsut a snippet.

Comment: Quelklef I was talking about @IanAuld's answer, not your question.