# python exec behaving differently between 2.7 and 3.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, exec

The below code snippet is getting different outputs from Python 2.7 and 3.3.

```
data = {'_out':[1,2,3,3,4]}
codes = ['_tmp=[]',
         '[_tmp.append(x) for x in _out if x not in _tmp]',
         'print(_tmp)']
for c in codes:
    exec(c,{},data)
```

Output from Python 2.7:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Output from Python 3.3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    exec(c,{},data)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <listcomp>
NameError: global name '_tmp' is not defined
```

To fix the error in Python 3.3, I simply set the globals to be as the same as locals, that is `exec(c,data,data)`.  Any idea why Python 3.3 is not behaving as that in 2.7?

Comment: even more interesting - it works just fine when using simple `for` loop instead of comprehension (which is by the way - incorrect way to operate with your list)

Comment: Yup, for loop works, that's why I thought it was a bug. Thanks for the comprehensive answer.  Issue 13557 is a great find!

Comment: Two things or relevance here changed in 3.0.  `Exec` is now a function instead of a statement. The body of comprehensions is now executed in a separate namespace instead of the namespace that contains the comprehension.

Comment: Also see [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2220699/4014959), especially the excellent [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29456463/4014959) by Antti Haapala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be known and **desired** behaviour, see issue 13557 
https://bugs.python.org/issue13557

and further in

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#interaction-with-dynamic-features

> **The eval() and exec() functions do not have access to the full environment for resolving names**. Names may be resolved in the local and global namespaces of the caller. **Free variables are not resolved in the nearest enclosing namespace, but in the global namespace**.

You can solve the above problem by not using list comprehension with local variables method calls, or by providing variables through global scope

#### Loops instead

```
data = {'_out':[1,2,3,3,4]}
codes = ['_tmp=[]', """
for x in _out: 
  if x not in _tmp: 
    _tmp.append(x)
""",
         'print(_tmp)']

for c in codes:
    exec(c, {}, data)
```

#### Global environment

```
data = {'_out':[1,2,3,3,4]}
codes = ['_tmp=[]',
         '[_tmp.append(x) for x in _out if x not in _tmp]',
         'print(_tmp)']
for c in codes:
    exec(c, data)
```