# How to calculate mathematical term packed in a string (python)

Tags: python, string, loops, python-3.x

I'm having a problem which I had for ages without finding a solution.

The code is this:

```
    Df = range(100)
    function = '3*x+4'
    for i in Df:
        listoffunction = list(function) #Will return ['3', '*', ...]
        for obj in listoffunction:
            if obj == 'x' :
                obj = i
        resultfori = ''
        for part in listoffunction:
            resultfori.join(part) #until here everything is fine.
                                  #resultfori is the following: '3*i+4'
                                  #with i the number of Df
```

Here is my problem: How can I calculate this term? I've tried it with the `exec` command but it always returns `None`. Why? I want it for example if i is 3 to return 13. Can you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why 12?  `3*3+4` could reasonable be evaluated to 13 or 21, but I don't see a 12 coming out of that.

Comment: Have you heard of SymPy? And you may want to try `eval` instead of `exec`

Comment: Related: "`exec` ignores the return value and always returns `None`"  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29456463/2308683.

Comment: Of course 13 (facepalm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
x = input()
s = '3*x + 4'
print eval(s)
```

Comment: I had to adapt the code a bit but the system behind the code worked perfectly fine! thx!