# How to get results out of a Python exec()/eval() call?

Tags: python, exec, eval

I want to write a tool in Python to prepare a simulation study by creating for each simulation run a folder and a configuration file with some run-specific parameters.

```
study/
  study.conf
  run1
    run.conf
  run2
    run.conf
```

The tool should read the overall study configuration from a file including (1) static parameters (key-value pairs), (2) lists for iteration parameters, and (3) some small code snippets to calculate further parameters from the previous ones. The latter are run specific depending on the permutation of the iteration parameters used.

Before writing the run.conf files from a template, I need to run some code like this to determine the specific key-value pairs from the code snippets for that run

```
code = compile(code_str, 'foo.py', 'exec')
rv=eval(code, context, { })
```

However, as this is confirmed by the Python documentation, this just leads to a `None` as return value.

The code string and context dictionary in the example are filled elsewhere. For this discussion, this snippet should do it:

```
code_str="""import math
math.sqrt(width**2 + height**2)
"""

context = {
    'width' : 30,
    'height' : 10
}
```

I have done this before in Perl and Java+JavaScript. There, you just give the code snippet to some evaluation function or script engine and get in return a value (object) from the last executed statement -- not a big issue.

Now, in Python I struggle with the fact that eval() is too narrow just allowing one statement and exec() doesn't return values in general. I need to import modules and sometimes do some slightly more complex calculations, e.g., 5 lines of code.

Isn't there a better solution that I don't see at the moment?

During my research, I found some very good discussions about [Pyhton eval() and exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python) and also some tricky solutions to circumvent the issue by [going via the stdout](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577585-universal-eval-to-string-function/) and parsing the return value from there. The latter would do it, but is not very nice and already 5 years old.

Comment: How have you ended up taking this approach at all? Could you not, for example, make the configuration files `.py` and `import` the appropriate file for each run? Or parse them within the module that needs them? It seems unnecessary and fragile to go via `compile` and `exec`/`eval`. Could you provide additional context on the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The "return" value of exec is stored in "context". `result = context['your_variable_name']`

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The purpose is to keep the study specification in one file readable for scientists. Having a file like this par1 = [1,2,3], par2=12, par3= "code snippet"

Comment: Was there more to that sentence? Could you [edit] the question to add context?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Finally, I have chosen your alternative proposal to go via .py and import. This really leads to a neat solution. Thanks!

Comment: @John no problem; in that case i suggest you write up and accept your own answer, rather than accepting one that wasn't your eventual solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this whole `exec()` / `eval()` thing in Python is a bit weird ... I have chose to re-design the whole thing based on a proposal in the comments to my question (thanks @jonrsharpe).

Now, the whole study specification is a `.py` module that the user can edit. From there, the configuration setup is directly written to a central object of the whole package. On tool runs, the configuration module is imported using the code below

```
import imp

# import the configuration as a module
(path, name) = os.path.split(filename)
(name, _) = os.path.splitext(name)
(file, filename, data) = imp.find_module(name, [path])

try:
    module = imp.load_module(name, file, filename, data)
except ImportError as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit(1)
finally:
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

The `exec` function will modify the *global* parameter (dict) passed to it. So you can use the code below

```
code_str="""import math
Result1 = math.sqrt(width**2 + height**2)
"""
context = {
    'width' : 30,
    'height' : 10
}

exec(code_str, context)

print (context['Result1']) # 31.6
```

Every variable  `code_str` created will end up with a key:value pair in the `context` dictionary. So the dict is the "object" like you mentioned in JavaScript.

#### Edit1:

If you only need the result of the last line in `code_str` and try to prevent something like `Result1=...`, try the below code

```
code_str="""import math
math.sqrt(width**2 + height**2)
"""

context = { 'width' : 30, 'height' : 10 }

lines = [l for l in code_str.split('\n') if l.strip()]
lines[-1] = '__myresult__='+lines[-1] 

exec('\n'.join(lines), context)
print (context['__myresult__'])
```

This approach is not as robust as the former one, but should work for most case. If you need to manipulate the code in a sophisticated way, please take a look at the  [Abstract Syntax Trees](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html)

Comment: Surprising that this works ... tried a similar approach before with exec(code_str,context,mylocals) which required to tag the return variable in the code snipped as global.

Comment: This might be a solution -- even though I would prefer something without postulating a convention as "use this name for the value"

Comment: It is also possible to get the results of EVERY expression in the code_str(returned as a list of numbers). But then how can you know the meaning of each result?

Comment: hehe ... that is really ugly ... but working! Thanks for the hints!!

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar needs, and finally figured out a approach by playing with ast:

```
import ast
code = """
def tf(n):
  return n*n
r=tf(3)
{"vvv": tf(5)}
"""
ast_ = ast.parse(code, '<code>', 'exec')
final_expr = None
for field_ in ast.iter_fields(ast_):
    if 'body' != field_[0]: continue
    if len(field_[1]) > 0 and isinstance(field_[1][-1], ast.Expr):
        final_expr = ast.Expression()
        final_expr.body = field_[1].pop().value
ld = {}
rv = None
exec(compile(ast_, '<code>', 'exec'), None, ld)
if final_expr:
    rv = eval(compile(final_expr, '<code>', 'eval'), None, ld)
print('got locals: {}'.format(ld))
print('got return: {}'.format(rv))
```

It'll eval instead of exec the last clause if it's an expression, or have all execed and return None.

Output:

```
got locals: {'tf': <function tf at 0x10103a268>, 'r': 9}
got return: {'vvv': 25}
```