# Parsing a file as an array with eval/exec in python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to read a line from a file, that already looks like an array, and convert it to an array using this:

```
eval('points='+lineFromFile)
print(points)
```

It works, when I try this:

```
points=[(1, 0, 0, 0), (4752/8677, 7260/8677, 0, -35/8677)]
print(points)
```

but this does not:

```
eval('points=[(1, 0, 0, 0), (4752/8677, 7260/8677, 0, -35/8677)]')
print(points)
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think you're mixing up `exec` and `eval`. You would need to either do `exec('points=[(1, 0, 0, 0), (4752/8677, 7260/8677, 0, -35/8677)]')` or (much better) `points = eval('[(1, 0, 0, 0), (4752/8677, 7260/8677, 0, -35/8677)]')`

Comment: Adding to what @MorganThrapp suggests, I recommend reading [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python). ... and: Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: If the contents of a file look like valid Python, `import` is the preferred way of  loading and parsing it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer the "how can I fix it" part of the question and suggest that you use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
points = ast.literal_eval(lineFromFile)
```

This has the side benefit that it should be *safe* from malicious code execution and is generally cleaner and easier to read.  The downside is that as the name implies, this will only evaluate python *literals* (no variables).

Another option is to use `json.loads` -- Depending on the input string, this *may* work and will probably be faster.  From what I can tell of your example, `json` *won't* work, but I mention it here just in case.

---

If you must use `eval/exec` (**I hope you trust the creator of the file!**), then you're best bet is probably to do something like:

```
points = eval(lineFromFile)
```

rather than trying to add the variable name to the string and then `exec` it.  You can do some things to try to make `eval` a little safer, but at the end of the day, you're [probably only giving yourself a false sense of security](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) if you do that...