# eval("a += b") in python 3.5.2

Tags: python-3.x

I was just running some code I had written for a learning exercise and suddenly ran into an error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax", from `eval("alist += [foo]")`. To try and understand I just made a simple module:

```
a = 5
eval("a += 1")
print(a)
```

and indeed it gives the same error, even when I just ran the first 2 lines directly into the Python console. Now I've only been doing Python a few days so I'm no expert but I'm 99% sure this should just work. `a+=1` works. `exec("a+=1")` works. But `eval("a+=1")` does not, nor does `eval("a-=1")`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is `eval()` not supposed to have this `+=` function? Are others able to do this, and it's some issue with my own Python? Do I have some really strange setting on?

Comment: ["The *expression* argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python

Comment: Thanks for the link Celeo, but there is so much information there I find it almost impossible to find the explicit answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `eval()` must be either a code object or an *expression*. Assignment in Python is a *statement*.

Comment: Ah now that's the clarification I needed - the difference between a statement and an expression, and which eval() requires. I guess it was kinda a silly question. Clearly I wanted exec().