# While loop Invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I'm trying to use this code to create a while loop from a string, but it's not working. This is the string that I call with the eval() function:

```
    'while True:\n\vprint("What role do you want?")\n\vAnswer = Reformat(raw_input())\n\vif Answer in RoleArray:\n\v\vPlayArray[0].append(Answer)\n\vif Answer == "Mafia":\n\v\v\vMafia.append(User)\n\v\velif Answer == "Sheriff":\n\v\v\vSheriff = User\n\v\velif Answer == "Doctor":\n\v\v\vDoctor = User\n\v\vdel RoleArray[RoleArray.index(Answer)]\n\velse:\n\v\vprint("That is not a role. Please check you spelling. [Mafia/Sheriff/Doctor/Townsperson]")'
```

And this is the error that shows up:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
eval('while True:\n\vprint("What role do you want?")\n\vAnswer = Reformat(raw_input())\n\vif Answer in RoleArray:\n\v\vPlayArray[0].append(Answer)\n\vif Answer == "Mafia":\n\v\v\vMafia.append(User)\n\v\velif Answer == "Sheriff":\n\v\v\vSheriff = User\n\v\velif Answer == "Doctor":\n\v\v\vDoctor = User\n\v\vdel RoleArray[RoleArray.index(Answer)]\n\velse:\n\v\vprint("That is not a role. Please check you s')
File "<string>", line 1
while True:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There is an alternate way to execute this code properly, but I would like to know why it isn't working.
Thanks.

Comment: Why are using `\v`?

Comment: You want `exec`, not `eval`, I think.

Comment: Also, for whatever you're doing, I strongly recommend against using `eval()\exec()`

Comment: @Blorgbeard Your correct. He needs `exec()`. `eval()` is for Python expressions, not compound statements.

Comment: you need `\t` instead of `\v`

Comment: @Blorgbeard He needs `eval()`. He attempts to execute Python code withing Python interpreter.

Comment: As another side note, this sounds a bit like an X/Y problem. Don't ask how to fix your solution. Ask about how to solve your _actual_ problem.

Comment: @DYZ No, he needs `exec()`. Either way, both should be avoid.

Comment: @leaf Ok, I see. You are right.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely culprit is both your use of `\v` instead of `\t` for tabs *and* your use of `eval`. You need to fix both:

Fixing both removes the syntax error:

```
>>> exec("while True:\n\tprint('yup')\n\tbreak")
yup
```

Using the vertical tab `\v` causes a syntax error:

```
>>> exec("while True:\n\vprint('yup')\n\vbreak")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2
    ♂print('yup')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And so does using `eval`, which is intended only for expressions:

```
>>> eval("while True:\n\tprint('yup')\n\tbreak")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    while True:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2220699/2615940) for an explanation of the differences between `eval` and `exec`.

It's possible you have other syntax errors as well, but I'm not going to try to debug that very long line.

Additionally, you should **strongly** reconsider your use of the dynamic code consuming functions like `eval` and `exec`. Even if your code's intended use doesn't present any security risk, they make things much more difficult to debug and maintain. The cases where they can't be avoided are exceedingly rare.

Comment: The use of \v is working fine, but I will keep \t in mind. Thx.

Comment: @GreenHawk1220 Hmm... what OS and python version are you using? That's odd that it would cause a syntax error for me and not you.

Answer (score 0):

After veiwing comments, I realize that I was being really dumb as to not use `exec()` instead of `eval()`, since one gives me a variable, and the other gives me a variable. Thank you, Blorgbeard!

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's working? Whenever I run it using `exec()` I get a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @leaf You may be seeing a similar issue that I'm getting. Are you using `\v` or `\t` for the tabs?

Comment: @skrrgwasme I am using `\v` and it does not work. In fact, when I print the escape character in the idle, it prints a strange empty box.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't. I was misreading it. Exec() with \t solved the problem. Thx guys.