# Matplotlib - "contains_point" function not finding the points within the polygon

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to check whether the points (i.e. listed within a file) coincide within the polygons (i.e. identified within another file). However, the code is just not showing any matches, even though I am sure that there are. Please take a look at the code and let me know whether I made an error.

```
# BoxPlot.py
# Determine whether the ship is located in a particular anchorage

import csv
import matplotlib.path as mplPath
import numpy as np

source_anchorage = "C:\\Users\\Tugboats\\" + \
                   "Tugboats - Terminal Coordinates V003.csv"
source_ship_locations = "C:\\Users\\Tugboats\\" + \
                        "TuggingActivity.csv"
target_file = "C:\\Users\\Tugboats\\" + \
              "OUT - TuggingActivity.csv"
location_processed = []

with open(source_anchorage, 'r') as f:
    inputReader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")

    # Loading all the data points into the anchorage names as a tuple
    for row in inputReader:
        if row["Acronym"] not in location_processed:
            location_processed.append(row["Acronym"])
            anchorage_name = row["Acronym"].__str__()
            exec("%s = %s" % (anchorage_name, []))

        # Build the polygon with the anchorage_name
        exec("%s.append(%s)" % (anchorage_name, (float(row["Longitude"]), float(row["Latitude"]))))

# Convert all anchorage names into numpy arrays
for location in location_processed:
    exec_create_polygon = "%s = mplPath.Path(np.array(%s))" % (location, location)
    # print(exec_create_polygon)
    exec(exec_create_polygon)

# Code to mark up all the location codes within the CSV file
with open(source_ship_locations, 'r') as f:
    inputReader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")

    output_file = open(target_file, 'w+', newline="")
    output_writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=",")

    for row in inputReader:
        for location in location_processed:
            exec_intersect = "%s.contains_point([%.9f, %.9f])" % \
                             (location, float(row["LastEntryLong"]), float(row["LastEntryLat"]))
            # print(exec_intersect)
            if exec(exec_intersect) == True:
                print("Match!")
                output_writer.writerow([row["Job_ID"],
                                        row["EarliestTimestamp"],
                                        row["LatestTimestamp"],
                                        row["NumberOfRecords"],
                                        row["License"],
                                        row["ExtShipMMSI"],
                                        row["1stEntryLat"],
                                        row["1stEntryLong"],
                                        row["LastEntryLat"],
                                        row["LastEntryLong"],
                                        row["FirstEntrySOG"],
                                        row["LastEntrySOG"],
                                        location.__str__()])
                break
        output_writer.writerow([row["Job_ID"],
                                row["EarliestTimestamp"],
                                row["LatestTimestamp"],
                                row["NumberOfRecords"],
                                row["License"],
                                row["ExtShipMMSI"],
                                row["1stEntryLat"],
                                row["1stEntryLong"],
                                row["LastEntryLat"],
                                row["LastEntryLong"],
                                row["FirstEntrySOG"],
                                row["LastEntrySOG"],
                                None])
```

Comment: create shorter version with some data in code so everyone could run it.

Comment: I don't see any “contains_point” in your code.

Comment: BTW: why do you use `exec()` ? can't you use dictionary with variables ? ie. `vars[anchorage_name] = []` instead of `exec("%s = %s" % (anchorage_name, []))`

Comment: There are too many polygons for me to create the polygons manually. That is why I chose to create the variables from a "CSV" file, containing the vertices of the polygon, on-the-fly.

Comment: I asked to create simple example polygon only for test - so we could run it. Now nobody can test you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the mistake is within my code. I realize that there is a difference between using `eval` and `exec`. `eval` returns the result of the statement in the code while `exec` only produces the side effects of the code. Hence, the line `if exec(exec_intersect) == True:` should be changed to `if eval(exec_intersect) == True:` instead. Making this change allowed the code to operate flawlessly.

For more information on the difference between `eval` and `exec`, refer to the following link: [Difference between eval, exec and compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python)