# Why do I get this "error" when I use the exec statement in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, exec

If I use the `exec` statement for a `for` statement, an error occurs.

My code:

```
exec 'for i in A_'+aws_n+'_DATI[:]:'
exec '    a_'+aws_n+'_tt += {datetime.datetime.strptime(A_'+aws_n+'_DATI[n], "%Y%m%d%H%M")}'
exec '    n  += 1'
```

---

Result:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws_merge.py", line 140, in <module>
    exec 'for i in A_'+aws_n+'_DATI[:]:'
  File "<string>", line 1
    for i in A_156_DATI[:]:
                          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing**
```

---

However, in the above code, if you remove the `exec` statement and manually process the variable `aws_n`, it will run without any problems.

```
for i in A_156_DATI[:]:
    print n
    n  += 1
```

Why is not it running?

Comment: There's almost never a good reason to use `exec`. And using it to dynamically create variable names, like your `A_156_DATI`,  is _definitely **not**_ a good reason. But if you wish to learn more about `exec` (and `eval`), please see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29456463/4014959).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, *do not ever* use `exec()`. It is completely unnecessary and [dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). Second, `exec()` executes a complete statement. `for i in A_156_DATI[:]:` is not a complete statement, but a part of a loop statement. If you *really* want to do a silly thing, put all lines of the loop together:

```
exec 'for i in A_'+aws_n+'_DATI[:]: a_'+aws_n+'_tt += ...; n  += 1'
```

For your reference, `[:]` in your case is not needed.