# Python 3 - exec() Vs eval() - Expression evaluation

Tags: python

After reading [query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2220699/3317808).

below python code is still not clear,

```
>>> exec('print(5+10)')
15
>>> eval('print(5+10)')
15
```

In `bash` world,

`exec` replace the shell with the given command.

`eval` execute arguments as a shell command.

---

**Question:**

Expression is a computation that evaluates to a value

To evaluate any **expression** in python(in my case `print(5+10)` from above python code), How `eval()` works different from `exec()` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How eval() works different from exec() ?

In your two cases, both `eval()` and `exec()` *do*, do the same things. They print the result of the expression. However, they are still both different.

The `eval()` function can only execute Python *expressions*, while the `exec()` function can execute *any valid Python code*. This can be seen with a few examples:

```
>>> eval('1 + 2')
3
>>> exec('1 + 2')
>>> 
>>> eval('for i in range(1, 11): print(i)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 1, in <module>
    eval('for i in range(1, 11): print(i)')
  File "<string>", line 1
    for i in range(1, 11): print(i)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> exec('for i in range(1, 11): print(i)')
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
>>>
```

Comment: Note that in OP's case, they both print 15 because the `print` function prints whenever it is evaluated.

Comment: So, why should I use `eval()` when `exec()` accepts any valid python code? where expressions are part of it. Am not asking whether, `exec()` accepts any python code.

Comment: @overexchange You really shouldn't use _either_ function as they are both dangerous. You could make the case that `eval()` would be _slightly_ less useful because it is only limited to expressions, but you should generally avoid using both, and use an alternative method instead.

Comment: @overexchange Look at the example in the answer. If you use `exec()` you don't get the result as a value. `exec('1 + 2')` performs the addition, but there's no way to get the result from it. You would have to do `exec('somevar = 1 + 2')`