# python, get variable value from string and variable concatination

Tags: python

I have argument in my script called attach_sub which take 2 argument

```
 attach_sub (host_id, vdc_sub_id)
```

I need  to provide attach_sub function a second argument which is the value of

prm_vdc_id variable

let say

```
prm_vdc_id = 5
```

I got a variable called  vdc_sub_id  which should be yielding the value of  prm_vdc_id

```
vdc_sub = 'prm'
vdc_sub_id = vdc_sub+'_vdc_id'
'prm_vdc_id'
```

but I am getting vdc_sub_id  value as a string and not the  actual

value of prm_vdc_id to be assign to the function

in short I want the function to take vdc_sub_id as its second argument

with a value of 5 in this case

```
attach_sub (host_id, vdc_sub_id)
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) - or variations thereof

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're probably doing something wrong here, but the reason why you're getting a string is because you're adding the two strings. If you want the variable which corresponds to the string value, do:

```
eval(vdc_sub_+"_vcd_id")
```

A better way of going about this would be to us a dictionary of `sub_ids`, where any possible value of `vdc_sub` corresponds to a `xxx_vdc_id`:

```
sub_ids = {'prm': 5}
```

Now, the equivalent of `xxx_vdc_id` would be `sub_ids[xxx]`.

Comment: this worked for me ,but there recommendations to avoid eval ,is there a better  way  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `exec(vdc_sub_+"_vcd_id")`, but you probably shouldn't code this way.

Comment: Why use `exec` over `eval`?

Comment: @Sebastian in my experience, they are fairly interchangeable.

Comment: [Not entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704229/python-3-exec-vs-eval-expression-evaluation/44704337#44704337)