# Execute function when certain word is found in string in python?

Tags: python, pseudocode

I'm working on a program for my school's programming outreach club, What I'm trying to do is have the user type in a string and the program searches the string. For example, they would type something like

```
moveInstant(4, 8)
```

and it would execute function

```
def moveInstant(targetX, targetY)
    pyautogui.moveTo(targetX, targetY)
```

Make sense? basically taking a long string and converting each instance of pseudo code into a predefined function with arguments. The idea is that a user could input a full txt file and it could be executed by the program.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am curious to know what the pseudo code will look like or how you are going to implement the 'string matching'. But:

1. Once you got the right function names and parameters, you can just use the [exec statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) to execute it. If not only the side effect but the return value of a function is what you want, use `eval` ([Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python)). Or,
2. Do some clean-up job for the text file and execute it using the [execfile function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile).

Noted that statements like `eval` or `exec` are potentially harmful, and that's why your 'string matching' for untrusted inputs is important.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `eval()` method. 
[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#eval)

Example:

```
>>> def test(x):
...   print(x)
>>> test(3)
>>> 3
>>> y = "test(124)"
>>> eval(y)
>>> 124
```