# Strange behaviour using timeit + exec

Tags: python, python-3.7, timeit

I've come across some strange behaviour trying to time python scripts. Minimum example:

foobar.py:

```
foo = 'Hello'
print(''.join(c for c in foo if c not in 'World'))
print(''.join(c for c in 'World' if c not in foo))
```

timer.py:

```
import timeit
timeit.repeat(stmt="exec(open('foobar.py').read())", repeat=1, number=1)
```

When I run foobar.py, I get the expected output:

```
> python3 foobar.py 
He
Wrd
```

However, when I run timer.py, I get the following error:

```
> python3 timer.py
He
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timer.py", line 2, in <module>
    timeit.repeat(stmt="exec(open('foobar.py').read())", repeat=1, number=1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/timeit.py", line 237, in repeat
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals).repeat(repeat, number)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/timeit.py", line 204, in repeat
    t = self.timeit(number)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/timeit.py", line 176, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in <genexpr>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Perhaps the most bizzare thing about it is that the first print statement in foobar.py works fine, while the second one does not. Executing foobar.py using exec without timeit wrapper works fine as well.

Anyone have an explanation for this odd behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not limited to `timeit` in combination with `exec`, but an issue with `exec` alone: The statements are being executed in a local namespace and the generator inside `str.join` uses another (new) local namespace, where the previously set `foo` isn't known.

> Class definition blocks and arguments to `exec()` and `eval()` are special in the context of name resolution. A class definition is an executable statement that may use and define names. These references follow the normal rules for name resolution with an exception that unbound local variables are looked up in the global namespace. The namespace of the class definition becomes the attribute dictionary of the class. The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods – this includes comprehensions and generator expressions since they are implemented using a function scope. This means that the following will fail:
>
> ```
> class A:
>     a = 42
>     b = list(a + i for i in range(10))
> ```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names

Also see [list comprehension in exec with empty locals: NameError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132645/list-comprehension-in-exec-with-empty-locals-nameerror) for example.

As a fix, you can set the globals dictionary with the second argument of [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), so all statements use the same dictionary:

```
timeit.repeat(stmt="exec(open('foobar.py').read(), locals())", repeat=1, number=1)
```

Or you could just drop `exec` altogether and use `import`:

```
timeit.repeat(stmt="import foobar", repeat=1, number=1)
```

By the way, executing `exec(open('foobar.py').read()` directly also only works if you're on the global (module) scope. If you'd simply put it inside a function, it will stop working and show the same error as if called by `timeit`.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation and the fix works. I believe the relationship to timeit must be that timeit causes the execution to occur withing a class definition scope?

Comment: You're right, I misread it. Strange thing is though that `exec(open('foobar.py').read())` called directly works fine without issues. So it must be that timeit adds *some* scope to the whole execution context, moving the definition of `foo` outside of the global scope?