# Python Syntax Errors with Python Anywhere

Tags: python, syntax, pythonanywhere

I'm using Python with DataCamp and Python Anywhere, and they seem to disagree on what a syntax error is. I've recently just started, so I tried this line of code:

```
n = 5
while n > 0:
   print (n)
   n = n - 1
print ('Blastoff!')
```

It runs like it's supposed on DataCamp, but with Python Anywhere, I get the following error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 5
    print ("Blastoff!")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know what it's referencing or trying to tell me. The error message is unhelpful, and I don't know why I'm getting two different evaluations here.

Comment: Are you running python2.x ?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki: this would work in Python 2.

Comment: Are you running this in an interactive interpreter? Then you must include a blank line between the `n = n - 1` and the `print` line.

Comment: It's possible that the Python Anywhere service verifies that your code is valid by its standards before the interpreter executes it. If that's the case, it could be that they don't want the space after your `print`s: `print('Blastoff!')`, instead. Although, I'm not sure why it wouldn't raise the same error for `print (n)` (unless it does and this one is just masking it).

Comment: @ZachGates: The spaces are not a problem.

Comment: The code you're running is not the code that you posted - the quotes are different. I would, therefore, suspect that the error is actually earlier in your code (perhaps an unclosed quote or bracket)

Comment: The line `File "<stdin>", line 5` is a hint that the code is run in an interactive shell.

Answer (score 2):

When *pasting* into interactive interpreter, you must have an **empty line** after a block statement, before the next statement. Here's the output from the Python Anywhere interpreter embedded on http://www.python.org:

```
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan 13 2017, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> n = 5
>>> while n > 0:
...    print (n)
...    n = n - 1
... print ('Blastoff!')
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    print ('Blastoff!')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Writing anything in the first column to `...` will cause this `SyntaxError`, even though legal in a source file. This is because all compound statements are passed into [`exec(compile(... 'single'))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python) when completed; and the python REPL is being a bit stupid here, thinking that it was just one statement, when it is in fact `while` followed by a `print`.

Hitting enter so that the prompt returns to `>>>`  before `print` will fix the problem in interactive interpreters:

```
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan 13 2017, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> n = 5
>>> while n > 0:
...    print (n)
...    n = n - 1
... 
5
4
3
2
1
>>> print ('Blastoff!')
Blastoff!
>>>
```

But notice that the `while` loop now runs as soon as the compound statement is terminated, i.e. before the `>>>` prompt shows again.

There are other shells besides the standard Python REPL. One popular, ipython, has a console shell that will recognize copy-pasted content and run this one correctly:

```
% ipython
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: n = 5
   ...: while n > 0:
   ...:    print (n)
   ...:    n = n - 1
   ...: print ('Blastoff!')
   ...: 
5
4
3
2
1
Blastoff!

In [2]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Both PythonAnywhere and the shell will treat anything within the `...` as part of the first statement, meaning that anything after a `if` or `with` or `while` or `for` that starts with 3 dots is supposed to be executed when the first statement is evaluated.

If you had an `if` statement, any code entered while the `...` is there will be executed when the if statement is evaluated.