# Python : pass variable name as argument

Tags: python

I have a function `f(x)` in which many local variables are created. `x` is a string with the same name as one of these local variables and I would like to change this local variable by changing `x`. What is the clean way to do this? Currently I am using a lot of `if/elif` statements.

Some dummy code to represent my problem:

```
def f(x):
         a = [1,2,3]
         b = [2,3,4]
         c = [3,4,5]
         if x == "a":
                     a[0] = 10
         elif x == "b":
                     b[0] = 10
         elif x == "c":
                     c[0] = 10
         return a,b,c
```

I would like for the right variable to change value but using all these if/elif statements feels a bit redundant.

Comment: show us some code please

Comment: Can you be more specific - e.g. post some code. Are you saying you want a variable inside `f` to take a value you pass in - but it depends on a string? Is this heading towards key word args?

Comment: Mind just froze for a moment there.

Comment: why do you need 2 variables with the same name with different purposes??? or i did not understand your question - please copy your code to the question

Comment: I will add code, hold on a moment

Comment: If you need to access a variable via a string holding a name, you don't want individual variables - you want a dictionary.

Comment: lets wait for the code example , seems like no one understood him

Comment: I think what the OP actually wants  is `global`

Comment: Does this clarify my question?

Comment: Well, cross that. Your code seems correct @HolyMonk . There is usually not many options for replacing `if/else`. And since you are using only 3 such statements, the code is not messy or such .

Comment: In my real example there are some more than 3 variables, but using a dictionary I still get reasonably elegant code.
Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 5):

## Use a `dict`

Simply, use a dict:

```
def f(x):
    values = {
        "a": [1,2,3],
        "b": [2,3,4],
        "c": [3,4,5]
    }
    values[x][0] = 10
    return values["a"], values["b"], values["c"]
```

If you *really really* want, use your original code and do `locals()[x][0] = 10` but that's not really recommended because you could cause unwanted issues if the argument is the name of some other variable you don't want changed.

Answer (score 4):

use dictionary like this:

```
def f(x):
     d = {"a" :[1,2,3],"b" : [2,3,4],"c" : [3,4,5]}
     d[x][0] = 10

     return d
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input is a string and you want to refer to a variable that matches that string you can use `globals()` like this:

```
globals()['x']
```

This way you can get the value and/or edit its contents.

Comment: Ok, so, 1) using `globals()` is a bad idea 99.999% of the time, and 2) you don't know whether x is a name at the global scope anyway. what if `x` is first created inside a `main` function, which then calls `f`? globals() won't have an 'x' entry in that case.

Comment: How else is he going to access the variable, except maybe using `locals()`? Sure he can rewrite the code, but this answer is for this specific situation.

Comment: This is a classic X-Y problem, you answer their question too literally, use a `dict` instead

Comment: I guess it's a moot point now, since OP's edited post clarifies that it really doesn't have anything to do with differently scoped variables.

Answer (score -2):

> You can use `exec()` and put your code in argument as a string

```
def f(x):
    a = [1,2,3]
    b = [2,3,4]
    c = [3,4,5]
    exec(x + "[0] = 10")

    return a,b,c

print f("a")
# ([10, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Sure you _can_, but you _shouldn't_. `exec` is both a security hazard and a performance hog. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python?rq=1