# Python define and call function represented by string

Tags: python, string, function, compilation, runtime

Assume that we have a string

```
function_string = 'def main():\n\treturn(1)'
```

How can this be compiled as a function during runtime and then be executed?

This is my current attempt, unfortunately it raises a NameError expressing that `main` is not defined:

```
self.run():
    exec(self.formatted_function_string) # similar to 'function_string' in the example
    print(main())
```

Comment: but, *why?* ...

Comment: for using external text source as script(update!)

Comment: @dsgdfg Then OP can execute that "external text source" on its own, or import it properly. No need to try and hack Python for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to call a Python script from another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script)

Comment: @DeepSpace you're right but did you have any trick `update an exec without change exec`, i think he want use an `exec` as `python-shell`

Comment: I assume that you are aware that `eval` and `exec` should generally be avoided because they can be a security risk. If not, please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: What about replacing `print(main())` by: `print(locals().get("main", lambda: None)())` ?

Comment: For some excellent info on exec and related topics, please see [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, executing / evaluating arbitrary strings is a security risk. But if you *really* want to do this, you need to pass `exec` an appropriate globals dict. The natural choice here is to pass it the `globals()` dict, so that whatever names your `exec` defines get put into the global namespace.

```
def test(argstring):
    exec(argstring, globals())
    print(main())

function_string = 'def main():\n\treturn(1)'
test(function_string)
print(main)
```

**typical output**

```
1
<function main at 0xb7196cd4>
```

Comment: Cleaner is to `exec` in a dedicated dictionary and retrieve the desired value afterwards.

Comment: @DavisHerring Good point; I was just showing the simplest way to do it that requires minimal changes to the OP's code.

Comment: Certainly that's closer to their code; (I smell XY and hope that) the cleaner answer is closer to their overall intent.