# Creating vaiables by looping though external text file line by line

Tags: python, list, variables

If i have a text file that contains an x number of lines like:

```
hostINFO = ['hostTYPE', 'hostOS', 'hostENV', 'hostNAME', 'hostIP', 'dbUNAME', 'dbPWD', 'dbPORT', 'orgNAME', 'nrdsTOKEN']
```

How would I create a python script that would:

1. import a line as a variable list so that i can refer to it as hostINFO[0] or hostINFO[1] etc....
2. execute the script against the variables
3. when completed go back to the host.txt file and get the next line and continue till no more lined exist.

update....

i changed my hosts.txt file format to be a comma delimited:

```
hostTYPE,hostOS,hostENV,hostNAME,hostIP,dbUNAME,dbPWD,dbPORT,orgNAME,nrdsTOKEN`
```

deploy.py

```
with open("hosts.txt") as f:
for line in f:
    hostINFO = line.strip().split(',')
```

Comment: Is the elements in ``hostInfo`` the lines of the file, or is each line in the file as ``hostINFO = [ .... ]`` ?

Comment: it is each line of the file

Comment: May I ask what your final goal is, i.e. what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Take a look at this question on [eval and exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python)

Comment: i want to be able to update the host.txt file with new lines and have the python script execute against the new line.

Comment: Check out my answer and see if it helps you. (But why don't just update the code files themselves instead of a separate text file?)

Comment: Maybe the [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) module to parse .ini-like files will suit your future needs? I guess it depends on the use case, though.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that [evaluating or executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python) code from files is a [serious vulnerability](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/), and you should really be sure that you have control of what's in the file.

You can convert text file content into variables with something like:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readline():
        exec(line)
        first_element = hostINFO[0]    # hostTYPE
        second_element = hostINFO[1]   # hostOS
        # ...
```

See also [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using some regex recipe :

```
import re
pattern='\w+'

with open('hosts.txt','r') as f:
    for i in f:
        hostINFO=re.findall(pattern,i)
        print(hostINFO)
        print(hostINFO[0])
        print(hostINFO[1])
        #after exec complete it goes for next_line in file
```

output:

```
['hostINFO', 'hostTYPE', 'hostOS', 'hostENV', 'hostNAME', 'hostIP', 'dbUNAME', 'dbPWD', 'dbPORT', 'orgNAME', 'nrdsTOKEN']
hostINFO
hostTYPE
```