# How to manipulate VCF contacts using VObject?

Tags: python, vobject

suppose i have built a VObject called `vobj` (e.g., built  via `vobject.readComponents(vcfStr)`) and want to add a new key:value pair to it:

```
  print('k=%s v=%s' % (k,v))
  try:
      stmnt1 = "vobj.add('%s')" % (k)
      print('stmnt1:"%s"' % stmnt1)
      eval(stmnt1)

      print('vobj after add\n'+20*'#'+'\n')
      vobj.prettyPrint()
      stmnt2 = "vobj.%s.value = '%s'" % (k,v)
      print('\n'+20*'#'+('\nstmnt2:"%s"' % stmnt2))
      eval(stmnt2)
  except Exception as e:
      print('wazzup?!',e)
```

all the extra prints and the `try:except` are because i can't
make it work!  here's the output produced:

```
  k=bday v=1931-02-10
  stmnt1:"vobj.add('bday')"
  vobj after add
  ####################

   VCARD
      VERSION: 3.0
      PRODID: -//Apple Inc.//Mac OS X 10.12.3//EN
      N:  Foo Bar 
      FN: Foo Bar
      EMAIL: foo@bar.com
      params for  EMAIL:
         TYPE ['INTERNET', 'WORK', 'pref']
      ...
      BDAY: 

  ####################
  stmnt2:"vobj.bday.value = '1931-02-10'"
  wazzup?! invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

i have three specific questions:

1. VObject makes use of `object.attribute` "dot" notation,
   and the only way i've found to handle arbitrary key names
   is using `eval()`.  there must be a more pythonic way?
2. evaluation of the first statement `stmnt1` works, and changes
   `vobj` as expected, producing an unbound slot for `BDAY`.
   but `stmnt2` fails with bad syntax and i don't know why.
3. i have also tried `stmnt2 = "vobj.%s.value = ['%s']" %
   (k,v)`, making the value a list, because of the two
   alternatives on the [VObject README](https://github.com/eventable/vobject):

   ```
    j.email.value = 'jeffrey@osafoundation.org'
    ...
    j.org.value = ['Open Source Applications Foundation']
   ```

   does it matter whether a string atom or list is used?

Comment: can you include the code where you create the vcard?

Comment: @wpercy thanks for your attention!  i've generated the vcard lots of ways, eg, `vobj = vobject.vCard()`, via `vobject.readComponents(vcfStr)`...  the `prettyPrint()` call seems to show it's well-formed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to simplify your code, and ended up with:

```
import vobject

s = 'BEGIN:VCARD\r\nFN:John Smith\r\nN:Smith;John;;;\r\nEND:VCARD'
vobj = vobject.readOne(s)

vobj.add('bday')
vobj.prettyPrint()

vobj.bday.value = '1931-02-10'
vobj.prettyPrint()
```

which produced:

```
> python test.py
VCARD
   FN: John Smith
   N:  John  Smith 
  BDAY: 
VCARD
   FN: John Smith
   N:  John  Smith 
   BDAY: 1931-02-10
>
```

which seems to be what was expected.

**Question 1**
There's not generally a need for arbitrary names in vObjects, because the specifications dictate what values are required, and they're all handled by the *vobject* code.

A common pattern when adding a value is to save a reference to the added attribute, and access it directly, like:

```
notes = vobj.add("NOTES")
notes.value = "The content of my notes"
```

or, just do it inline:

```
vobj.add("NOTES").value = "Notes in one line"
```

Or you can access it directly:

```
vobj.notes.value = "New notes content"
```

**Question 2**
The problem here is nothing to do with *vobject*, but rather with Python.  In Python, `eval` only works for *expressions*.  To dynamically compile and execute a *statement* (like your `stmnt2`), you need to use `exec`.

If you change

```
eval(stmnt2)
```

to

```
exec(stmnt2)
```

your example code sets the BDAY property without an exception.

See [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile) for a full explanation.

**Question 3**
Yes, it matters.  The type of values of the various attributes of a vObject are determined by the specifications.  Some have a single value, others are (optionally) a set of values.  *vobject* doesn't enforce this, currently.