# Using exec() to run lambda function from string

Tags: python, lambda, exec

I want to be able to bring in a lambda function from a txt file, and have it be able to run as if it were a normal section of code.

```py
chain = "What has to be broken up"

reduction = 'lambda chain: chain[0:8]'

x = exec(reduction)

print(x)      #only prints out 'None'

print(exec(x = reduction))    #causes error

print(exec(reduction)) #prints out 'None'
```

What I am hoping for the output to be is the first 8 characters of the string chain, 'What has'. How can I make this work to run the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a function, you have to use `()` after it.

To get the value of an expression in a string, you need to use `eval()`, not `exec()`. See [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile).

Since your lambda function has a parameter, you need to give it an argument when calling it.

```
chain = "What has to be broken up"
reduction = 'lambda c: c[0:8]'
x = eval(reduction)(chain)
print(x)
```

If you don't want to give it an argument, you should take out the parameter. But you still need to provide an empty argument list.

```
chain = "What has to be broken up"
reduction = 'lambda: chain[0:8]'
x = eval(reduction)()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do, but here's a guess. It uses [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) instead of `exec()` since what's in `reduction` is an expression:

```
chain = "What has to be broken up"
reduction = 'lambda string: string[0:8]'
x = eval(reduction)(chain)
print(x)  # -> What has
```