# Print variable by input

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to print variable name by `input`, Example:

```
a = 1
b = 2

what_variable = input('Which Variable?: ') #User for example introduces 'b'
```

```
Console: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

```
print(globals()[what_variable])
```

but it's not a good approach. Use a dict instead

Comment: Thank's, for my tasks, this is what I need! 
To everyone else, thank you very much for the answers!

Comment: You may want to use `locals()` instead. `globals()[what_variable]` will only work if `what_variable` is defined in the global scope.

Comment: I made a mistake when testing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec`:

```
var = input('Which Variable?: ')

exec("print(" + var + ")")
```

Output:

> ```
> Which Variable?: b
> 2
> >>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
print(eval(input('Which Variable?: ')))
```

You can also do

```
print(globals()[input('Which Variable?: ')])
```

Comment: Would not invoking `eval` also permit arbitrary code execution?

Comment: Avoid using `eval`. If you had this running on a server, I could enter in some of my own nasty python code: `import os; os.system('<the naughty rm rf command>')`

Comment: Yes, `eval`'s bad; but how does it differ from `exec`?

Comment: @SamChats, `eval` is only able to evaluate expressions which makes it *somewhat* safer than `exec`. `exec` allows you to execute any arbitrary python code. In my comment above, you actually can't put the `import os` part in the eval statement since it will raise a syntax error. However if `os` was already imported, then you could still run anything with `os.system(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers seem to address the obvious solution, it's not very 'Pythonic'. The main issues with these is, by far, safety. Let's say that your user inputs `apiKey`, and you *happen* to have a variable by that name... let's just say your bank statement is probably looking at a slight increase in magnitude. What most people in these answers don't realise is that using `.globals()[input()]` is no safer than `eval(input())`, because, shockingly, *people store private info in variables*. Alternatively, if it points to a method, e.g

```
a = print
b = os.system

eval(input())()
```

I could enter *any* function name there, and the damage would be done before the second `()` executes.

Why? Well, let's take a look at how `exec` and `eval` work (I won't go into the difference here, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile) for that). All they do is evaluate the string as Python code, and (simplifying here) return the value of the *eval*uation:

```
var1 = 3

print(eval("var1"))

# ====is equal to====

var1 = 3

print(var1)
```

(where `var1` as a string obviously comes from the input typed in)

But if someone enters something malicious, this is essentially the basis of an SQL injection:

(where `userInput` is substituted by a user's input into an `input()`)

```
userInput = "a + os.system('reboot now')"

print(eval(userInput))

# ====is equal to====

print(a + os.system('shutdown now')
```

and you suddenly find your computer's off.

Therefore, we'd either use a:

- Dictionary (or object): `x={a:1, b:2}`, then do `x[input()]`
- Array `x=[1, 2]`, then do `x[["a", "b"].index(input())]`
- Simply don't. Find a way to work around it. What's wrong with an `if/else` set? It's not good practise, because of the safety concerns outlined above. What most people seem to miss about dictionaries (or my array option) is that if you enter a malformed input (i.e not `a` or `b`), it would result in either uncaught errors being thrown, or `undefined`s being thrown around. And if you're going to do input validation, you're using an `if` statement anyway, so why not do it from the onset?