# Compile/exec failing to assign values within it's own scope, resulting in an internal syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

My python is doing something weird. I'm trying to execute a bit of code from string form using exec/eval/compile. Specifically exec, but's failing silently with a syntax error so I switched to a eval instead.

```
#start of document

print( compile( 'Test_val = 1;', 'None', 'eval' ) )

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lucasyoung/Desktop/Application/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    print( compile( 'Test_val = 1;', 'None', 'eval' ) )
  File "None", line 1
    Test_val = 1;
             ^
```

I did a bit of testing, and I can, for example, call a print statement via compile. I can call variables into existence, but I can't seem to be able to name them. And whats strange is that this is within the scope of the compiled code's own context.

I know that stack has a big insistence on hyper detailing questions, but I honestly just don't know what to say about this one. Exec is supposed to fire some code from a string. The code I'm calling is perfectly valid. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly there is a difference between eval() and exec()

eval() : The eval() method returns the result evaluated from the expression.

The eval function does the same for a single expression, and returns the value of the expression:

exec() : The exec() doesn't return any value, it returns None.

The exec function (which was a statement in Python 2) is used for executing a dynamically created statement or program:

therefore

`eval('Test_val = 1;')` is not a valid expression for eval.

`exec('test_val = 1;')` is a valid expression for exec

for in your case , you should use

```
print( compile( 'Test_val = 1;', 'None', 'exec' ) )
```

please check [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile) for more information

Comment: I want to thank you for your ver clear, concise, and correct answer!