# Execute instructions written in a string

Tags: python

I have a little problem, I have written a for loop as a string.

In PHP, with the help of function exec(), we can run the string which will eventually run the for loop defined inside the string.

Can we do such a thing in Python as well?

By example, I would like run follow it:

```
string="for i in range(1,(5+1)): print(str(i))"
```

How to run this in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile)

Comment: eval and exec are the correct solution, and they can be used in a safer manner.

Comment: How and why did you create this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exec` if you want to execute some statements:

```py
code = 'for i in range(1,(5+1)): print(str(i))'
exec(code)
```

If you want to evaluate an expression and get the value then you can use `eval`:

```py
value = eval('2+3')
print(value) # 5
```