# Can I use the calculator of the Python shell in my own code?

Tags: python, calculator

So I am working on a small assistant which is supposed to read websites, convert units etc. Me and my friend are still working on getting the first commands up, so we tried to make a calculator. It is supposed to be able to calculate calculations with multiple operators and brackets, like the Python Shell does. But there seems to be no way to just input a string into the shell to use it for this. All calculator codes we found were very long and couldn't handle more than one operator. Do we have to use a long script for this or is there an easier way? My partner wrote something like this, it seemed to be the easiest option:

```
calc = input()
calc2 = calc.split()
num1 = float(calc2[0])
num2 = float(calc2[2])
operator = calc2[1]

if operator == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif operator == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif operator == ("*" or "x"):
    print(num1 * num2)
elif operator == ("/" or ":"):
    print(num1 / num2)
elif operator == "//":
    print(num1 // num2)
elif operator == "**":
    print(num1 ** num2)
elif operator == "%":
    print(num1 % num2)
else:
    print("ERROR")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily do this with the `eval` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
calc = input()
result = eval(calc)
print(calc + " = " + str(result))
```

However, what you call "the calculator of the Python shell" is in fact a complete Python interpreter, so just like in a Python shell, you can input strings that will not just compute expressions, but also e.g. delete all your files:

```
import os; os.system("rm -f /")
```

Whether this is a problem is up to you.

Comment: You'd better highlight the fact that that piece of code there is dangerous or else a beginner will just randomly copy and paste it into their interpreter without thinking.

Comment: I removed the `-r` so that they are free to copypaste the "delete all your files" snippet into their interpreter

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

```
if "+" in s:
    print(s[0]+s[-1])
if "-" in s:
    print(s[0]-s[-1])
```

Using the subscriptions `[0]` and `[-1]` *(first element and last element)* 
will make whether the user adds spaces between the numbers and operator optional.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to input a string like "4 + 5"
then you need to check what operator is there so instead of saying if operator == X (because that's manual)  say

```
if "+" in String:
    String = String.split(" + ")
    print(String[0] + String[1])
if "-" in String:
    String = String.split(" - ")
    print(String[0] - String[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use exec

```
calc = input()
exec('res='+calc)
print(res)
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using `exec()` over `eval()`?

Comment: `exec` just executes the statement, returning only NONE. This is why I added the `'res='` inside the string. Compared to that, eval just accepts a single stament but returns the reuslt, such that `res=` was written outside in this case. This has also been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile)