# How to send message with exec() in discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, exec

I want to make a discord bot in python

this is my code:

```py
@app.event
async def on_message(message):
    sendu = exec(message.content)
    await message.channel.send(sendu)
```

if I send a message in discord and save in var `sendu` and use exec function to run the `sendu`
but every time I try my code example: `random.randint(1, 100)`
it returns this error, what is wrong with my code?

```
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message
```

Comment: [Exec doesn't return the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile#:~:text=eval%20and%20exec%20have%20these%20two%20differences%3A&text=eval%20returns%20the%20value%20of,really%20does%20not%20return%20anything), use eval instead. Also make sure only you can use a command like that, it is very dangerous to leave something like that unprotected.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message `Cannot send an empty message`, it looks like `sendu` is empty. Make sure it's not empty, and then try again!

Comment: I send msg in discord ran(random class).randint(1, 100)  But it returns error Im sure i send it as sendu is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

`exec()` from [programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec):

`exec()` doesn't return any value, it returns `None`.

The exec() method executes the dynamically created program, which is either a string or a code object.

Consider a situation, you are using a Unix system (macOS, Linux, etc) and you have imported `os` module. The os module provides a portable way to use operating system functionalities like read or write a file.

If you allow users to input a value using `exec(input())`, the user may issue commands to change file or even delete all the files using the command `os.system('rm -rf *')`.

try using `eval()` instead as it has a return value but be careful! as it is similar to `exec()`!