# Is it possible to get this df['homes']+df['flats'] out of string in python?

Tags: python, string

I have an issue with strings. Is it possible to get data frame and column name out of string? Like below,

```
my input:
    string = "df['homes']+df['age']"

I want this out of the string-like below

excepted output:

string = df['homes']+df['age']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> string = "df['homes']+df['age']"
>>> string = pd.eval(string)
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this, I was aware of eval. But the problem with eval is when we give division or too many arithmetic symbols it gives a wrong answer any other method to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the infamous [`exec()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2220699/13552470) method:

```
my_input = input()

exec(my_input)
```

#### But it is very dangerous, do not use the code snippet above.

See [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1933451/13552470)