# How can I dynamically define a function from user input?

Tags: python, lambda, exec

I'm trying to dynamically generate a function from user input. The user gives a function as a string input, gives the differents parameters, and I want to write a function that will change this string into a usable function. My idea so far was to use the `exec` function to create a `lambda` function constructed with a string like so : `exec("f = lambda {}:{}".format(', '.join(['x'] + parameter_list), function_string))`. This would give, for example, a string like `"f = lambda x, a:x+a"` to the `exec` function.

This technique works fine if I define the scope of `exec` to `globals()`, but I'd like my function to be local so that I can do something like this:

```
def define_function(function_string, parameter_list):
    exec("f = lambda {}:{}".format(', '.join(['x'] + parameter_list), function_string))
    return f
```

or like this :

```
def define_function(function_string, parameter_list):
    exec("return lambda {}:{}".format(', '.join(['x'] + parameter_list), function_string))
```

However, in the first case, it gives an error along the lines of "f is not defined". In the second case, meanwhile, it says that "return can only be used in a function". I understand why the second error occurs, but I wonder why my first try didn't work. Using `globals()` makes it work, but I'd rather not use it.

If you have any suggestions for other methods for achieving the same result, I'm interested in those as well.

**EDIT**

Using `eval` also raises an error :

```
line 9, in define_function
    eval("f = lambda {}:{}".format(', '.join(['x'] + parameter_list), function_string))
  File "<string>", line 1
    f = lambda x, a:x+a
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Use `eval` instead of `exec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: use `eval()`:

```
def get_func(param_list, result_str):
    return eval("lambda {}: {}".format(', '.join(['x'] + param_list), result_str))
```

Solution 2: if you really want to use `exec()`, do something like this:

```
def get_func(param_list, result_str):
    exec("f = lambda {}: {}".format(', '.join(['x'] + param_list), result_str))
    return locals()['f']
```

Some good info on the differences between `exec` and `eval` here: [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile)

---

I can see what you're trying to do in your question, by the way, and it's worth noting that the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) [pages](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) for `exec()` and `locals()` both explicitly warn that this won't work. Ditto, if you type `help(locals)` into the interactive interpreter, you get this message:

```
Help on built-in function locals in module builtins:

locals()
    Return a dictionary containing the current scope's local variables.

NOTE: Whether or not updates to this dictionary will affect name lookups in
the local scope and vice-versa is *implementation dependent* and not
covered by any backwards compatibility guarantees.
```