# Create object based on arguments

Tags: python

I would like to create object based on arguments I provided.

For example

```
abilities1 = {
    "empathy" : 1000
}

abilites2 = {
    "strength" : 100
}
```

And now I want to pass abilities dict to class which automatically determine if object should be Man class (strength ability in dict) or Women class (empathy ability in dict).

Is there any technique to write this class? I would like to avoid IFs.

Thank you in advance and sorry for stereotyping genders :)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `if`?

Comment: If I add more abilities, I would have to add all of them to that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at concept of python Meta Programming and based on conditions, can define your classes in simple string and use eval() and exec() keywords if I'm no mistaken.

You can take a look at this link:

[What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile)