# How to run a string with python

Tags: python-3.x, string

I'm trying to run a function that is inside a string variable in Python.
The code I'm using is:

```
def func1():
    return "Hello"

word = "func1()"
a = exec(word)
print(a)
```

But, instead of returning `Hello`, the script returns `None`.

Is it possible to run a command that I have in a string variable?

Comment: Note that `exec` return value is `None`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

Comment: You might want to use `eval` for this usage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile

Comment: Thank you both for your help. @StrangeSorcerer,'s answer was exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.