# Inbuilt python command to run user input script

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a inbuilt command to run user input as python script?
e.g.

```
a = 3
command("Enter command: ")
```

Then when run on terminal:

```
Enter command: print(a)
3
```

Comment: See [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are in fact builtin functions in python to run a python expression or a block of code (more than one statement and expression). These functions are `eval`, `exec` and `compile`.

Refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile) for more information.